# 64 bit ntohl() in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, endianness

The man pages for `htonl()` seem to suggest that you can only use it for up to 32 bit values. (In reality, `ntohl()` is defined for unsigned long, which on my platform is 32 bits. I suppose if the unsigned long were 8 bytes, it would work for 64 bit ints).

My problem is that I need to convert 64 bit integers (in my case, this is an unsigned long long) from big endian to little endian. Right now, I need to do that specific conversion. But it would be even nicer if the function (like `ntohl()`) would NOT convert my 64 bit value if the target platform WAS big endian. (I'd rather avoid adding my own preprocessor magic to do this).

What can I use? I would like something that is standard if it exists, but I am open to implementation suggestions. I have seen this type of conversion done in the past using unions. I suppose I could have a union with an unsigned long long and a char[8]. Then swap the bytes around accordingly. (Obviously would break on platforms that were big endian).

Comment: What is your platform? Most systems have platform-specific BE to LE conversion routines. Failing that, you could easily write one.

Comment: Take a look at my reply at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874617/supporting-byte-ordering-in-linux-user-space/874643#874643)

Comment: Just my 2cts, it is written clearly in the C standard (dont know which one, 89 or 99), that a long should be enough to store a pointer. A phrase, that does not appear in C++ standard however. Linux compilers that I have seen respects that, a long is 64 bits on 64 bits builds. However Microsoft has chosen a weird solution where long is 32 bits everywhere.

Comment: @JasonCoco You hit the nail on the head way back with this question was first asked I think, I posted an example answer below, I assume this is what you were getting at.

Comment: an actual answer to [the question is given here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022552/is-there-any-standard-htonl-like-function-for-64-bits-integers-in-c) for those interested

Answer (score 64):

Documentation: `man htobe64` on Linux (glibc >= 2.9) or FreeBSD.

Unfortunately OpenBSD, FreeBSD and glibc (Linux) did not quite work together smoothly to create one (non-kernel-API) libc standard for this, during an attempt in 2009.

Currently, this short bit of preprocessor code:

```
#if defined(__linux__)
#  include <endian.h>
#elif defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__NetBSD__)
#  include <sys/endian.h>
#elif defined(__OpenBSD__)
#  include <sys/types.h>
#  define be16toh(x) betoh16(x)
#  define be32toh(x) betoh32(x)
#  define be64toh(x) betoh64(x)
#endif
```

(tested on Linux and OpenBSD) should hide the differences. It gives you the Linux/FreeBSD-style macros on those 4 platforms.

Use example:

```
  #include <stdint.h>    // For 'uint64_t'

  uint64_t  host_int = 123;
  uint64_t  big_endian;

  big_endian = htobe64( host_int );
  host_int = be64toh( big_endian );
```

It's the most "standard C library"-ish approach available at the moment.

Comment: This doesn't work with android (which defines `__linux__` but provides the openbsd api)

Comment: @Stefan: That's horrific :(

Answer (score 21):

I would recommend reading this: http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t
ntoh64(const uint64_t *input)
{
    uint64_t rval;
    uint8_t *data = (uint8_t *)&rval;

    data[0] = *input >> 56;
    data[1] = *input >> 48;
    data[2] = *input >> 40;
    data[3] = *input >> 32;
    data[4] = *input >> 24;
    data[5] = *input >> 16;
    data[6] = *input >> 8;
    data[7] = *input >> 0;

    return rval;
}

uint64_t
hton64(const uint64_t *input)
{
    return (ntoh64(input));
}

int
main(void)
{
    uint64_t ull;

    ull = 1;
    printf("%"PRIu64"\n", ull);

    ull = ntoh64(&ull);
    printf("%"PRIu64"\n", ull);

    ull = hton64(&ull);
    printf("%"PRIu64"\n", ull);

    return 0;
}
```

Will show the following output:

```
1
72057594037927936
1
```

You can test this with ntohl() if you drop the upper 4 bytes.

Also You can turn this into a nice templated function in C++ that will work on any size integer:

```
template <typename T>
static inline T
hton_any(const T &input)
{
    T output(0);
    const std::size_t size = sizeof(input);
    uint8_t *data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&output);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        data[i] = input >> ((size - i - 1) * 8);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Now your 128 bit safe too!

Comment: I think your template version is broken, it ignores the last byte. To fix it I changed `size = sizeof(T);` and `input >> ((size-i-1)*8)`.

Comment: it is pure speculation on how the compiler abstraction for types that are larger than the register size will store the parts in memory. Who says they want to strictly respect little endian or big endian ? it could even be a design that is not platform dependent, such like it will be natural on an architecture, and unnatural in another. it does not matter because the "loading" code of the big integer into the registers is the same, and portable. But this choice is compiler dependent.

Comment: Accessing memory as uint8_t violates strict aliasing rule and is undefined behavior.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with structs? applying the treatment to each byte... It produces an error at first line (init of T) and with the `operator>>` missing.

Answer (score 16):

### Quick answer

```
#include <endian.h>    // __BYTE_ORDER __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#include <byteswap.h>  // bswap_64()

uint64_t value = 0x1122334455667788;

#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
value = bswap_64(value);  // Compiler builtin GCC/Clang
#endif
```

### Header file

As reported by [zhaorufei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64469/zhaorufei) (see her/his comment) `endian.h` is not C++ standard header and the macros `__BYTE_ORDER` and `__LITTLE_ENDIAN` may be undefined. Therefore the `#if` statement is not predictable because undefined macro are treated as `0`.

*Please edit this answer if you want to share your C++ elegant trick to detect endianness.*

## Portability

Moreover the macro `bswap_64()` is available for GCC and Clang compilers but not for Visual C++ compiler. To provide a portable source code, you may be inspired by the following snippet:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #define bswap_16(x) _byteswap_ushort(x)
  #define bswap_32(x) _byteswap_ulong(x)
  #define bswap_64(x) _byteswap_uint64(x)
#else
  #include <byteswap.h>  // bswap_16 bswap_32 bswap_64
#endif
```

See also a more portable source code: [Cross-platform `_byteswap_uint64`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46137633/938111)

### C++14 `constexpr` template function

Generic `hton()` for 16 bits, 32 bits, 64 bits and more...

```
#include <endian.h>   // __BYTE_ORDER __LITTLE_ENDIAN
#include <algorithm>  // std::reverse()

template <typename T>
constexpr T htonT (T value) noexcept
{
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
  char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value);
  std::reverse(ptr, ptr + sizeof(T));
#endif
  return value;
}
```

### C++11 `constexpr` template function

- C++11 does not permit local variable in `constexpr` function.
  Therefore the trick is to use an argument with default value.
- Moreover the C++11 `constexpr` function must contain one single expression.
  Therefore the body is composed of one return having some comma-separated *statements*.

```cpp
template <typename T>
constexpr T htonT (T value, char* ptr=0) noexcept
{
  return 
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&value), 
    std::reverse(ptr, ptr + sizeof(T)),
#endif
    value;
}
```

No compilation warning on both clang-3.5 and GCC-4.9 using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`
(see compilation and run output on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f8a9941c2904e18)).

### C++11 `constexpr` template SFINAE functions

However the above version does not allow to create `constexpr` variable as:

```
constexpr int32_t hton_six = htonT( int32_t(6) );
```

Finally we need to separate (specialize) the functions depending on 16/32/64 bits.
But we can still keep generic functions.
(see the full snippet on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25019ad184048704))

The below C++11 snippet use the [traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to exploit [Substitution Failure Is Not An Error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SFINAE) (SFINAE).

```
template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) == 2, T>::type
htonT (T value) noexcept
{
   return  ((value & 0x00FF) << 8)
         | ((value & 0xFF00) >> 8);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) == 4, T>::type
htonT (T value) noexcept
{
   return  ((value & 0x000000FF) << 24)
         | ((value & 0x0000FF00) <<  8)
         | ((value & 0x00FF0000) >>  8)
         | ((value & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
}

template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) == 8, T>::type
htonT (T value) noexcept
{
   return  ((value & 0xFF00000000000000ull) >> 56)
         | ((value & 0x00FF000000000000ull) >> 40)
         | ((value & 0x0000FF0000000000ull) >> 24)
         | ((value & 0x000000FF00000000ull) >>  8)
         | ((value & 0x00000000FF000000ull) <<  8)
         | ((value & 0x0000000000FF0000ull) << 24)
         | ((value & 0x000000000000FF00ull) << 40)
         | ((value & 0x00000000000000FFull) << 56);
}
```

Or an even-shorter version based on built-in compiler macros and C++14 syntax `std::enable_if_t<xxx>` as a shortcut for `std::enable_if<xxx>::type`:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == 2, T>
htonT (T value) noexcept
{
    return bswap_16(value);  // __bswap_constant_16
}

template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == 4, T>
htonT (T value) noexcept
{
    return bswap_32(value);  // __bswap_constant_32
}

template <typename T>
constexpr typename std::enable_if_t<sizeof(T) == 8, T>
htonT (T value) noexcept
{
    return bswap_64(value);  // __bswap_constant_64
}
```

#### Test code of the first version

```
std::uint8_t uc = 'B';                  std::cout <<std::setw(16)<< uc <<'\n';
uc = htonT( uc );                       std::cout <<std::setw(16)<< uc <<'\n';

std::uint16_t us = 0x1122;              std::cout <<std::setw(16)<< us <<'\n';
us = htonT( us );                       std::cout <<std::setw(16)<< us <<'\n';

std::uint32_t ul = 0x11223344;          std::cout <<std::setw(16)<< ul <<'\n';
ul = htonT( ul );                       std::cout <<std::setw(16)<< ul <<'\n';

std::uint64_t uL = 0x1122334455667788; std::cout <<std::setw(16)<< uL <<'\n';
uL = htonT( uL );                      std::cout <<std::setw(16)<< uL <<'\n';
```

#### Test code of the second version

```
constexpr uint8_t  a1 = 'B';               std::cout<<std::setw(16)<<a1<<'\n';
constexpr auto     b1 = htonT(a1);         std::cout<<std::setw(16)<<b1<<'\n';

constexpr uint16_t a2 = 0x1122;            std::cout<<std::setw(16)<<a2<<'\n';
constexpr auto     b2 = htonT(a2);         std::cout<<std::setw(16)<<b2<<'\n';

constexpr uint32_t a4 = 0x11223344;        std::cout<<std::setw(16)<<a4<<'\n';
constexpr auto     b4 = htonT(a4);         std::cout<<std::setw(16)<<b4<<'\n';

constexpr uint64_t a8 = 0x1122334455667788;std::cout<<std::setw(16)<<a8<<'\n';
constexpr auto     b8 = htonT(a8);         std::cout<<std::setw(16)<<b8<<'\n';
```

#### Output

```
               B
               B
            1122
            2211
        11223344
        44332211
1122334455667788
8877665544332211
```

#### Code generation

The online C++ compiler [gcc.godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/A6GXDt) indicate the generated code.

**`g++-4.9.2 -std=c++14 -O3`**

```
std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned char))==(1), unsigned char>::type htonT<unsigned char>(unsigned char):
    movl    %edi, %eax
    ret
std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned short))==(2), unsigned short>::type htonT<unsigned short>(unsigned short):
    movl    %edi, %eax
    rolw    $8, %ax
    ret
std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned int))==(4), unsigned int>::type htonT<unsigned int>(unsigned int):
    movl    %edi, %eax
    bswap   %eax
    ret
std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned long))==(8), unsigned long>::type htonT<unsigned long>(unsigned long):
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    bswap   %rax
    ret
```

**`clang++-3.5.1 -std=c++14 -O3`**

```
std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned char))==(1), unsigned char>::type htonT<unsigned char>(unsigned char): # @std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned char))==(1), unsigned char>::type htonT<unsigned char>(unsigned char)
    movl    %edi, %eax
    retq

std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned short))==(2), unsigned short>::type htonT<unsigned short>(unsigned short): # @std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned short))==(2), unsigned short>::type htonT<unsigned short>(unsigned short)
    rolw    $8, %di
    movzwl  %di, %eax
    retq

std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned int))==(4), unsigned int>::type htonT<unsigned int>(unsigned int): # @std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned int))==(4), unsigned int>::type htonT<unsigned int>(unsigned int)
    bswapl  %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    retq

std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned long))==(8), unsigned long>::type htonT<unsigned long>(unsigned long): # @std::enable_if<(sizeof (unsigned long))==(8), unsigned long>::type htonT<unsigned long>(unsigned long)
    bswapq  %rdi
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    retq
```

---

Note: my [original answer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aac0cf97ddc0702d) was not C++11-`constexpr` compliant.

<sub>This answer is in [Public Domain CC0 1.0 Universal](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/)</sub>

Comment: In `htonT()`, which would you give it a `char*` input parameter instead of using a local variable?

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau for your feedback. C++11 does not allow local variable in `constexpr` function :-( After one year and half, C++14 is more and more used than just C++11. Therefore I have updated the answer provide cleaner `constexpr` functions in C++14. Do you validate my changes? Cheers

Comment: endian.h is not C++ standard header. When it happened there's a endian.h file, it's even more dangerous if it not define  __BYTE_ORDER and __LITTLE_ENDIAN macro. Because undefined macro will be treated 0 and thus they equals.

__bswap_constant_XX  is gcc/clang specific.  I'd like to use compiler macro to get a minimal portable  solution for GCC/Clang/MSVC:
#ifdef __GNUC__   // also works for clang
    __builtin_bswap64/32/16
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#else
     _byteswap_ushort/_byteswap_ulong/_byteswap_uint64
#error Not supported
#endif

Comment: Thank you very much @zhaorufei :-)  I have improved the answer thanks to your feedback  :-)  Please have a look on the answer and tell me if this is OK. I have not yet compiled the snippets... Please also verify If the snippets are correct. Thank you. Take care

Answer (score 14):

To detect your endian-ness, use the following union:

```
union {
    unsigned long long ull;
    char c[8];
} x;
x.ull = 0x0123456789abcdef; // may need special suffix for ULL.
```

Then you can check the contents of `x.c[]` to detect where each byte went.

To do the conversion, I would use that detection code once to see what endian-ness the platform is using, then write my own function to do the swaps.

You could make it dynamic so that the code will run on any platform (detect once then use a switch inside your conversion code to choose the right conversion) but, if you're only going to be using one platform, I'd just do the detection once in a separate program then code up a simple conversion routine, making sure you document that it only runs (or has been tested) on that platform.

Here's some sample code I whipped up to illustrate it. It's been tested though not in a thorough manner, but should be enough to get you started.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TYP_INIT 0
#define TYP_SMLE 1
#define TYP_BIGE 2

static unsigned long long cvt(unsigned long long src) {
    static int typ = TYP_INIT;
    unsigned char c;
    union {
        unsigned long long ull;
        unsigned char c[8];
    } x;

    if (typ == TYP_INIT) {
        x.ull = 0x01;
        typ = (x.c[7] == 0x01) ? TYP_BIGE : TYP_SMLE;
    }

    if (typ == TYP_SMLE)
        return src;

    x.ull = src;
    c = x.c[0]; x.c[0] = x.c[7]; x.c[7] = c;
    c = x.c[1]; x.c[1] = x.c[6]; x.c[6] = c;
    c = x.c[2]; x.c[2] = x.c[5]; x.c[5] = c;
    c = x.c[3]; x.c[3] = x.c[4]; x.c[4] = c;
    return x.ull;
}

int main (void) {
    unsigned long long ull = 1;
    ull = cvt (ull);
    printf ("%llu\n",ull);
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that this just checks for pure big/little endian. If you have some weird variant where the bytes are stored in, for example, {5,2,3,1,0,7,6,4} order, `cvt()` will be a tad more complex. Such an architecture doesn't deserve to exist, but I'm not discounting the lunacy of our friends in the microprocessor industry :-)

Also keep in mind that this is technically undefined behaviour, as you're not supposed to access a union member by any field other than the last one written. It will probably work with most implementations but, for the purist point of view, you should probably just bite the bullet and use macros to define your own routines, something like:

```
// Assumes 64-bit unsigned long long.
unsigned long long switchOrderFn (unsigned long long in) {
    in  = (in && 0xff00000000000000ULL) >> 56
        | (in && 0x00ff000000000000ULL) >> 40
        | (in && 0x0000ff0000000000ULL) >> 24
        | (in && 0x000000ff00000000ULL) >> 8
        | (in && 0x00000000ff000000ULL) << 8
        | (in && 0x0000000000ff0000ULL) << 24
        | (in && 0x000000000000ff00ULL) << 40
        | (in && 0x00000000000000ffULL) << 56;
    return in;
}
#ifdef ULONG_IS_NET_ORDER
    #define switchOrder(n) (n)
#else
    #define switchOrder(n) switchOrderFn(n)
#endif
```

Comment: "may need special suffix for ULL" - and neither C89 nor C++ defines one that's portable. However, you can do x.ull = ((unsigned long long) 0x01234567) << 32 + 0x89abcdef; provided that long long really is 64bit.

Comment: Thanks, onebyone, I ended up just using 0x01 and detecting that.

Comment: Actually "return src" should be done for big-endian architectures, not little-endian.  Also, a more concise way to do the conversion on a little-endian CPU would be to compute the upper 32 bits of the result by using htonl() on the lower 32 bits of src and the lower 32 bits of the result by using htonl() on the upper 32 bits of src (hope that makes some sense...).

Comment: That's not right, is it, Lance? The question asked for the value in little endian - that means leave it alone on little-endian systems and swap it on big-endian systems.

Comment: Lance is right... I am on a little endian system and I am dealing with a big endian number. I like that suggestion Lance. You should write it up as an answer so it can be upvoted, and possibly accepted :).

I will make a decision soon on what to do and post more and hand out reputation.

Comment: The htonl() and related functions are intended to convert from host CPU byte order to network byte order.  Network byte order is big-endian, so a conversion has to be performed on little-endian machines.  The question was consistent with this - it stated that the function should "NOT convert my 64 bit value if the target platform WAS big endian".

Comment: Tom - I'd be happy to have an up-voted comment (I'm not sure whether that impacts rep or not...)

Comment: I realize I made a mistake in my post... I meant to say ntohl, not htonl... ::sigh:: sorry for the confusion. But I think it was clear from the context what I was looking for. I'll update the post now.

Comment: Tom, if the code given should be changed based on your latest update, it's a simple matter of changing "if (typ == TYP_SMLE)" to "if (typ == TYP_BIGE)" - this will change when the swap is done.

Comment: be careful not to do more work than actually necessary. don't confuse memory representation and register (compiler-abstracted integeres) representation : http://commandcenter.blogspot.fr/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: why just not use unsigned int a = 1; if(*((char *)&a) == 1) printf("little edian");

Comment: Sometimes you don't care what endianness this machine is, all you care is that the signature you got is backward, so you need to force swap the things. The "feature" where it does nothing if it is already in the specified endianness (`htonl`) goes against you. You might as well swap it yourself at that point, forget the standard things.

Comment: @KarimS That's UB. It violates aliasing rules. The optimizer is allowed to screw it up and not say anything. If you did the spirit of what you did by memcpy one byte to a char local, it's beautiful. Builtin memcpy will see what you mean and do the best thing, and it's defined. It is supposed to be okay with a char, good luck with that on reckless optimizers. You crippled its ability to have `a` in a register.

Answer (score 12):

some BSD systems has `betoh64` which does what you need.

Comment: Linux (glibc) too.  It's found in the <endian.h> header.

Comment: Hmm... I can't find the function in any of the endian.h headers. I am on my intel mac right now (running leopard). I also need to get this to work on Linux machines at school. I'm not sure which distro is running, but I am fairly certain they are i386 machines, little endian, and sizeof(unsigned long long) == 8.

Also, the function I would need is be64toh(). Any suggestions? I would prefer this solution to the other one.

Comment: my fault - what yo want should be betoh64. on FreeBSD, it's in /usr/include/sys/endian.h . The man page is byteorder(9).

According to FreeBSD notes, these were originally from NetBSD, and appear on FreeBSD after 5.x.

As I know, MacOSX is using lots of FreeBSD files as its backend (darwin) base - so there's a big chance that you may be able to use it.

Comment: @Francis: My sources indicate that it is present even in 4.3BSD.  @Tom: Autoconf looks for endian.h, sys/endian.h, and machinfo/endian.h; you may have to use different include paths on different platforms.

Answer (score 6):

one line macro for 64bit swap on little endian machines.

```
#define bswap64(y) (((uint64_t)ntohl(y)) << 32 | ntohl(y>>32))
```

Comment: @BjornRoche It will be easy to construct similar macro for big endian machines. `#include <endian.h>
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN` to tidy up the bswap64() API and make it platform independent.

Answer (score 5):

How about a generic version, which doesn't depend on the input size (some of the implementations above assume that `unsigned long long` is 64 bits, which is not necessarily always true):

```
    // converts an arbitrary large integer (preferrably >=64 bits) from big endian to host machine endian
    template<typename T> static inline T bigen2host(const T& x)
    {
        static const int one = 1;
        static const char sig = *(char*)&one; 

        if (sig == 0) return x; // for big endian machine just return the input

        T ret;
        int size = sizeof(T);
        char* src = (char*)&x + sizeof(T) - 1;
        char* dst = (char*)&ret;

        while (size-- > 0) *dst++ = *src--;

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Best solution so far. I would just replace the while with for, so the compiler can rely on the sizeof(T) to unroll the loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
uint32_t SwapShort(uint16_t a)
{
  a = ((a & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((a & 0xFF00) >> 8);
  return a;
}

uint32_t SwapWord(uint32_t a)
{
  a = ((a & 0x000000FF) << 24) |
      ((a & 0x0000FF00) <<  8) |
      ((a & 0x00FF0000) >>  8) |
      ((a & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
  return a;
}

uint64_t SwapDWord(uint64_t a)
{
  a = ((a & 0x00000000000000FFULL) << 56) | 
      ((a & 0x000000000000FF00ULL) << 40) | 
      ((a & 0x0000000000FF0000ULL) << 24) | 
      ((a & 0x00000000FF000000ULL) <<  8) | 
      ((a & 0x000000FF00000000ULL) >>  8) | 
      ((a & 0x0000FF0000000000ULL) >> 24) | 
      ((a & 0x00FF000000000000ULL) >> 40) | 
      ((a & 0xFF00000000000000ULL) >> 56);
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Why is the 16 bit function returning a 32 bit int?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
#define ntohll(x) ( ( (uint64_t)(ntohl( (uint32_t)((x << 32) >> 32) )) << 32) | 
    ntohl( ((uint32_t)(x >> 32)) ) )                                        
#define htonll(x) ntohll(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

I like the union answer, pretty neat. Typically I just bit shift to convert between little and big endian, although I think the union solution has fewer assignments and may be faster:

```
//note UINT64_C_LITERAL is a macro that appends the correct prefix
//for the literal on that platform
inline void endianFlip(unsigned long long& Value)
{
   Value=
   ((Value &   UINT64_C_LITERAL(0x00000000000000FF)) << 56) |
   ((Value &   UINT64_C_LITERAL(0x000000000000FF00)) << 40) |
   ((Value &   UINT64_C_LITERAL(0x0000000000FF0000)) << 24) |
   ((Value &   UINT64_C_LITERAL(0x00000000FF000000)) << 8)  |
   ((Value &   UINT64_C_LITERAL(0x000000FF00000000)) >> 8)  | 
   ((Value &   UINT64_C_LITERAL(0x0000FF0000000000)) >> 24) |
   ((Value &   UINT64_C_LITERAL(0x00FF000000000000)) >> 40) |
   ((Value &   UINT64_C_LITERAL(0xFF00000000000000)) >> 56);
}
```

Then to detect if you even need to do your flip without macro magic, you can do a similiar thing as Pax, where when a short is assigned to 0x0001 it will be 0x0100 on the opposite endian system.

So:

```
unsigned long long numberToSystemEndian
(
    unsigned long long In, 
    unsigned short SourceEndian
)
{
   if (SourceEndian != 1)
   {
      //from an opposite endian system
      endianFlip(In);
   }
   return In;
}
```

So to use this, you'd need SourceEndian to be an indicator to communicate the endianness of the input number. This could be stored in the file (if this is a serialization problem), or communicated over the network (if it's a network serialization issue).

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to use ntohl on the two parts seperately:

```
unsigned long long htonll(unsigned long long v) {
    union { unsigned long lv[2]; unsigned long long llv; } u;
    u.lv[0] = htonl(v >> 32);
    u.lv[1] = htonl(v & 0xFFFFFFFFULL);
    return u.llv;
}

unsigned long long ntohll(unsigned long long v) {
    union { unsigned long lv[2]; unsigned long long llv; } u;
    u.llv = v;
    return ((unsigned long long)ntohl(u.lv[0]) << 32) | (unsigned long long)ntohl(u.lv[1]);
}
```

Comment: your first function is htonll and uses ntohl() internally. both functions are interchangeable, correct? if so why are they implemented differently?

Comment: Oops, fixed. Strictly speaking, there are other options for endianness than big or little-endian - while you don't see them much anymore, on some very old systems, `htonl()` and `ntohl()` might behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

`htonl` can be done by below steps

- If its big endian system return the value directly. No need to do any conversion. If its litte endian system, need to do the below conversion.
- Take LSB 32 bit and apply 'htonl' and shift 32 times.
- Take MSB 32 bit (by shifting the uint64_t value 32 times right) and apply 'htonl'
- Now apply bit wise OR for the value received in 2nd and 3rd step.

Similarly for `ntohll` also

```
#define HTONLL(x) ((1==htonl(1)) ? (x) : (((uint64_t)htonl((x) & 0xFFFFFFFFUL)) << 32) | htonl((uint32_t)((x) >> 32)))
#define NTOHLL(x) ((1==ntohl(1)) ? (x) : (((uint64_t)ntohl((x) & 0xFFFFFFFFUL)) << 32) | ntohl((uint32_t)((x) >> 32)))
```

You can delcare above 2 definition as functions also.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename T>
static T ntoh_any(T t)
{
    static const unsigned char int_bytes[sizeof(int)] = {0xFF};
    static const int msb_0xFF = 0xFF << (sizeof(int) - 1) * CHAR_BIT;
    static bool host_is_big_endian = (*(reinterpret_cast<const int *>(int_bytes)) & msb_0xFF ) != 0;
    if (host_is_big_endian) { return t; }

    unsigned char * ptr = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&t);
    std::reverse(ptr, ptr + sizeof(t) );
    return t;
}
```

Works for 2 bytes, 4-bytes, 8-bytes, and 16-bytes(if you have 128-bits integer). Should be OS/platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you are coding on Linux using 64 bit OS; most systems have `htole(x)` or `ntobe(x)` etc, these are typically macro's to the various `bswap`'s

```
#include <endian.h>
#include <byteswap.h>

unsigned long long htonll(unsigned long long val)
{
    if (__BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN) return (val);
    else return __bswap_64(val);
}

unsigned long long ntohll(unsigned long long val)
{
    if (__BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN) return (val);
    else return __bswap_64(val);
}
```

Side note; these are just functions to call to swap the byte ordering. If you are using little endian for example with a big endian network, but if you are using big ending encoding then this will unnecessarily reverse the byte ordering so a little "`if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN`" check might be require to make your code more portable, depening on your needs.

Update: Edited to show example of endian check

Answer (score 0):

universal function for any value size.

```
template <typename T>
T swap_endian (T value)
{
    union {
        T src;
        unsigned char dst[sizeof(T)];
    } source, dest;

    source.src = value;
    for (size_t k = 0; k < sizeof(T); ++k)
        dest.dst[k] = source.dst[sizeof(T) - k - 1];

    return dest.src;
}
```

Comment: It is not enough to just swap the bytes. You have to know whether the input value is *already* in the target endian or not, and then swap bytes only if needed.  The `hton...()` and `ntoh...()` functions handle that kind of logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
union help64
{
    unsigned char byte[8];
    uint64_t quad;
};
uint64_t ntoh64(uint64_t src)
{
    help64 tmp;
    tmp.quad = src;
    uint64_t dst = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        dst = (dst << 8) + tmp.byte[i];
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It isn't in general necessary to know the endianness of a machine to convert a host integer into network order.  Unfortunately that only holds if you write out your net-order value in bytes, rather than as another integer:

```
static inline void short_to_network_order(uchar *output, uint16_t in)
{
    output[0] = in>>8&0xff;
    output[1] = in&0xff;
}
```

(extend as required for larger numbers).

This will (a) work on any architecture, because at no point do I use special knowledge about the way an integer is laid out in memory and (b) should mostly optimise away in big-endian architectures because modern compilers aren't stupid.

The disadvantage is, of course, that this is not the same, standard interface as htonl() and friends (which I don't see as a disadvantage, because the design of htonl() was a poor choice imo).