# Supporting byte ordering in Linux user space

Tags: c, linux, endianness

I'm writing a program on Linux in C to analyze core files produced from an embedded system. The core files might be little endian (ARM) or big endian (MIPS), and the program to analyze them might be running on a little endian host (x86) or big endian (PowerPC).

By looking at the headers I know whether the core is LE or BE. I'd rather my program *not* need to know whether the host it runs on is little or big endian, I'd like to use an API to handle it for me. If there is no better option, I guess I'll start relying on #ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__.

In the Linux kernel we have cpu_to_le32 et al to convert from native byte ordering to little endian, etc. In user space there is htonl et al, which convert from native to big endian but no equivalent for native to little endian that I can find.

Can anyone suggest a suitable API for user space?

**Edit**: Just to be clear, I'm looking for an API which already knows whether my CPU is big or little endian and swaps byes accordingly. I don't want to have to litter my code with #ifdefs for this. I'm not just looking for code snippets to swap bytes; thank you for those, but that wasn't the point.

Comment: But with these code snippets you can trivially write a macro that does that, therefore creating your own "API", no?

Comment: What sort of embedded system is it? Can't you simply use some cross gdb to look at the core files?

Comment: Could I write my own API? Sure. I just want to avoid #ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__ if there is a cleaner, more maintainable way to do it via an existing API which already knows whether my CPU is big or little endian.

Comment: As for what kind of embedded system it is: its a perfectly normal and boring PowerPC. I already have a cross-compiled gdb for it. gdb is great for many things, but not everything. For example it is spectacularly bad at searching all of memory for a particular pattern; you write a gdb macro which takes forever and a day to finish searching a medium size core file.

Comment: An approch to avoid using `#ifdef BIG_ENDIAN` was explained here: https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you're actually trying to do (read ELF core dump files without having to worry about endian issues), I believe using libelf, available [here](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/pds.cgi?ports/devel/libelf) with a nice tutorial [here](http://people.freebsd.org/~jkoshy/download/libelf/article.html), would be a good choice.

This library works transparently with big- and little-endian ELF files and runs just fine under Linux despite its FreeBSD origins (the usual "./configure" and "make" sequence is all you'll need to build it).  For grins I tried the "reading a program header table" example (with minor modifications to get it to build) on an x86 core file as well as a MIPS big-endian core file, it appears to "just work".

Comment: I've been using libbfd to open the core and locate each section, but for the contents it just hands over a big array of unsigned characters  (leaving it to me to handle the endianness of anything within it). I'll investigate libelf instead, perhaps it is more helpful in this regard.

Comment: The elf32_xlatetom() and elf32_xlatetof() functions might be interesting for that purpose, API is documented e.g. at http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-5172/6mbb7btp9?a=view

Answer (score 19):

`#include <arpa/inet.h>` is nice and portable, but only guarantees `{ntoh,hton}{s,l}`.  If you need conversions on 64-bit values, or endian flipping on big-endian (where `ntoh` and `hton` do nothing), it won't be enough.

On Linux (glibc), [`#include <endian.h>`](http://sources.redhat.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/~checkout~/libc/string/endian.h?cvsroot=glibc) provides the following, defined as appropriate for the current machine.

```
htobe16  be16toh    htole16  le16toh
htobe32  be32toh    htole32  le32toh
htobe64  be64toh    htole64  le64toh
```

On *BSD, [`#include <sys/endian.h>`](http://cvsweb.se.netbsd.org/cgi-bin/bsdweb.cgi/~checkout~/src/sys/sys/endian.h) provides these same macros.

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the neon coprocessor and the memory is contiguous (example a video frame) you could execute swap16 on the frame using the q registers (128bytes) in this way; of course, you have to watch for alignment issues

```
void swap16(void *__restrict src16)
{
    const void *start = src16;
    const void *end = src16 + FRAME_SIZE;
    asm volatile (
        "1: pld     [%0, #0x100]\n"
        "vld2.8         {q0,q1}, [%0]\n"
        "vmov           q2,q0\n"
        "vst2.8         {q1,q2}, [%0]!\n"
        "cmp            %1,%0\n"
        "bne            1b\n"
        : /* empty output operands */
        : "r" (start), "r" (end)
        : "cc", "memory"
        );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you treat the file as a byte array, then you control which order you pick the bytes out, and the endian-ness of your CPU actually ends up not mattering.

This is also highly useful in terms of dealing with alignment problems.  Your core dump might concievably have unaligned references in it.  I know that's highly unlikely, but it could be due to corruption as well.  This is another problem that is avoided by treating the file as a byte array.

I used this approach in implementing jhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard network bytswapping functions in apa/inet.h:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong); // Host to network
uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort); // Host to network
uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong); // Network to host
uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort); // Network to host
```

Network byte order is big-endian. So, these functions mean:

```
hton*: Host endian to big endian
ntoh*: Big endian to host endian
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need an API to do it? Simply write your own function to call `htonl()` (or whatever produces BE) then simply reverse the bytes. That doesn't sound so hard.

Something like:

```
union {
    struct {
        unsigned char c0;
        unsigned char c1;
        unsigned char c2;
        unsigned char c3;
    } ch;
    uint32_t ui;
} u;
unsigned char t;

u.ui = htonl (hostlong);
t = u.ch.c0; u.ch.c0 = u.ch.c3 ; u.ch.c3 = t;
t = u.ch.c1; u.ch.c1 = u.ch.c2 ; u.ch.c2 = t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the kernel-provided headers in /usr/include/linux/byteorder/ such as __cpu_to_be32() and __be32_to_cpu()

Take also a look at the /usr/include/linux/types.h file where you can define types as explicit big/little endian plain integers, which help a lot since any mismatch will be detected at compile time.

Comment: Nice find. From a quick look, however, it seems that you still need something like an "#ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__" to conditionally include either linux/byteorder/little_endian.h or linux/byteorder/big_endian.h. Not a huge deal, but still...

Comment: That's right, but the good way is to write without using `#ifdef BIG_ENDIAN`, see https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Answer (score 1):

Given that switching endian-ess [is easy](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/index.html?ca=drs-#N1028E), I always ended up using custom code like that, keeping a strict rule about what representation I use in the code, and handling endianity at the end points (input and output).

Answer (score 1):

You could just write your own (these are based on Apple's routines):

```
static inline uint16_t Swap16(uint16_t x)
{
    return ( (x << 8) | (x >> 8) );
}

static inline uint32_t Swap32(uint32_t x)
{
    return ( (((x ^ (x >> 16 | (x << 16))) & 0xff00ffff) >> 8) ^ (x >> 8 | data << 24) );
}
```

Then you can define conditional macros:

```
#ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__
# define htols(x) Swap16(x)
# define htoll(x) Swap32(x)
#else
# define htols(x) (x)
# define htoll(x) (x)
#endif
```

If you're happy with Intel assembler code, you can even do this:

```
// Swap16 is unchanged

static inline uint32_t Swap32(uint32_t x)
{
    __asm__ ("bswap %0" : "+r" (x));
    return ( x );
}
#ifdef __i386__
static inline uint64_t Swap64(uint64_t x)
{
    __asm__ ("bswap  %%eax\n\t"
             "bswap  %%edx\n\t"
             "xchgl  %%eax, %%edx"
             : "+A" (x));
    return ( x );
}
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
static inline uint64_t Swap64( uint64_t x )
{
    __asm__ ("bswap  %0" : "+r" (x));
    return ( x );
}
#endif
```