# endian.h on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cross-platform

I'm working on a cross platform project on which I need `endian.h`. But this file is not on Windows or Mac OS X.

Is there any way I can get it to work without the file, or is there a way to get the file?

Comment: You might want to explain where it *is* and why you think you need it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm working on a cross platform project, which I need endian.h.

endian.h is not cross-platform. It is very clearly marked as such: "These functions are nonstandard."

You don't *need* endian.h. What you need is some of the functionality that that header provides. All three of Windows, Linux, and Mac (and Solaris, and others) do provide native to big endian functions, and they use the near-standard names `htons`, `ntohl`, etc. Will these suit your needs? If so, use them. They are portable. If not, you'll have to, well, roll your own. It's not hard. Or look to Boost. It probably has exactly what you want.

Comment: There is no 64 bit swap function.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022552/is-there-any-standard-htonl-like-function-for-64-bits-integers-in-c) for `htonll`.