# Read from a binary file to a dynamic array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, binaryfiles

So, i've this binary file E1.bin and what i need is to read the info there and put it in a dynamic array os structures.

This is my structure where i need to put the info:

```
    typedef struct sala local, *plocal; 

    struct sala{     
    int id;     
    int capacidade;    
    int liga[3];     
};
```

The content of the binary file is organized like so:
1
50
3
-1
-1
2
50
3
-1
-1
3
50
1
4
2
(and so on)

Each struct of the array needs to store 5 values: first is for id, second for capacidade, third for liga[0], fourth for liga[1] and fifth for liga[2], then goes to the next struct and does the same.

And this is the function im using to open the file and try to read it:

```
local *carregaEspaco(local *v, int *tam){

    char espaco[15];

    printf("Nome do ficheiro do espaco a carregar: ");
    gets(espaco);

    FILE *fe = fopen(espaco, "rb");

    if(!fe){
        printf("Erro ao abrir o ficheiro %s.\n\n", espaco);
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Ficheiro %s aberto.\n\n", espaco);

    local *aux = NULL;
    int i = 1;

    while(fread(&aux, sizeof(local), 1, fe) == 1){

        if(aux == NULL)
            aux = malloc(sizeof(local));
        else
            aux = realloc(v, sizeof(local) * i);

        if(aux){
            v = aux;
            i++;
        }
    }

    *tam = i - 1;    

    fclose(fe);
    return v;
}
```

I dont understand why isnt this working. Can anyone help me with this please ?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readwrite-structure-file-c/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing Structs to a file in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997141/writing-structs-to-a-file-in-c)

Comment: *is not working* means nothing. Say what is expected and what happens.

Comment: @RobertHarvey not really, i alreayd have that. What i need is to save the info in the array os structs. Like: first five numbers for the first struct, second 5 numbers for the second and so on… and i would like to have a way to confirm that is saving correctly

Comment: I suggest you follow the GeeksForGeeks example, or the example in the "Writing Structs to a file in c" article first.

Comment: Thank you for the help, i solved the problem !