# Unit testing STM32 with Ceedling

Tags: testing, makefile, stm32, ceedling

I need to do some unit testing in my C project, which will be used in STM32F0 processor. I could test my abstraction code on x64 gcc, but the problem is i need a platform with little-endian (STM32F0 is little-endian by default). I tried to do some mods in project.yml file.

```
:project:
  :use_exceptions: FALSE
  :use_test_preprocessor: TRUE
  :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
  :build_root: build
#  :release_build: TRUE
  :test_file_prefix: test_

#:release_build:
#  :output: MyApp.out
#  :use_assembly: FALSE

:environment:

:extension:
  :executable: .out

:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - ../CDynTransport/src/
  :support:
    - test/support

:defines:
  # in order to add common defines:
  #  1) remove the trailing [] from the :common: section
  #  2) add entries to the :common: section (e.g. :test: has TEST defined)
  :commmon: &common_defines []
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST

:cmock:
  :mock_prefix: mock_
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :plugins:
    - :ignore
    - :callback
  :treat_as:
    uint8:    HEX8
    uint16:   HEX16
    uint32:   UINT32
    int8:     INT8
    bool:     UINT8

:tools:
  :test_compiler:
    :executable: arm-none-eabi-gcc
    :arguments:
      - "${1}"
      - '-c'
      - '-g'
      - '-mcpu=cortex-m0'
      - '-mthumb'
      - '-Wall'
      - '-Wno-address'
      #- '-std=c99'
      #- '-pedantic'
      - -I"$": COLLECTION_PATHS_TEST_TOOLCHAIN_INCLUDE               #expands to -I search paths
      - -I"$": COLLECTION_PATHS_TEST_SUPPORT_SOURCE_INCLUDE_VENDOR   #expands to -I search paths
      - -D$: COLLECTION_DEFINES_TEST_AND_VENDOR  #expands to all -D defined symbols
      - -I"$": COLLECTION_PATHS_SOURCE_INCLUDE_VENDOR
      - '-DTEST'
      - '-DUNITY_EXCLUDE_STDINT_H'
      - '-DUNITY_EXCLUDE_LIMITS_H'
      - '-DUNITY_EXCLUDE_SIZEOF'
      - '-DUNITY_INCLUDE_DOUBLE'
      - '-DUNITY_SUPPORT_TEST_CASES'
      - '-DUNITY_INT_WIDTH=32'
      - '-DUNITY_LONG_WIDTH=32'
      - '-DUNITY_INCLUDE_CONFIG_H'
  :test_linker:
    :executable: arm-none-eabi-gcc
    :arguments:
      - '-lm'
      - '-mcpu=cortex-m0'
      - '-mthumb'
      - '-specs=nosys.specs'
      #- '-T targets/gcc_armcortexM3/qemu.ld'
  :test_simulator:
    :executable: qemu-system-arm
    :arguments:
      - -cpu cortex-m3
      - -M lm3s6965evb
      - -no-reboot
      - -nographic
      - -kernel

:plugins:
  :load_paths:
    - vendor/ceedling/plugins
  :enabled:
    - stdout_pretty_tests_report
    - module_generator
```

But still i have problems with compilation. For example:

```
Test 'test_command.c'
---------------------
Generating runner for test_command.c...
Compiling test_command_runner.c...
In file included from /home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/vendor/unity/src/unity.h:16:0,
                 from build/test/runners/test_command_runner.c:22:
/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/vendor/unity/src/unity_internals.h:11:26: fatal error: unity_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "unity_config.h"
                          ^
compilation terminated.
ERROR: Shell command failed.
> Shell executed command:
'arm-none-eabi-gcc build/test/runners/test_command_runner.c -c -g -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -Wall -Wno-address -I"test" -I"test/support" -I"../CDynTransport/src" -I"/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/vendor/unity/src" -I"/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/vendor/cmock/src" -I"build/test/mocks" -DTEST -I"../CDynTransport/src" -DTEST -DUNITY_EXCLUDE_STDINT_H -DUNITY_EXCLUDE_LIMITS_H -DUNITY_EXCLUDE_SIZEOF -DUNITY_INCLUDE_DOUBLE -DUNITY_SUPPORT_TEST_CASES -DUNITY_INT_WIDTH=32 -DUNITY_LONG_WIDTH=32 -DUNITY_INCLUDE_CONFIG_H'
> And exited with status: [1].

rake aborted!
ShellExecutionException: ShellExecutionException
/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/lib/ceedling/tool_executor.rb:78:in `exec'
/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/lib/ceedling/generator.rb:95:in `generate_object_file'
/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/lib/ceedling/rules_tests.rake:17:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/lib/ceedling/task_invoker.rb:74:in `invoke_test_results'
/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:68:in `block in setup_and_invoke'
/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/lib/ceedling/test_invoker.rb:32:in `setup_and_invoke'
/home/slawek/CentralInterface/CDynTransportTest/vendor/ceedling/lib/ceedling/tasks_tests.rake:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => build/test/results/test_command.pass => build/test/out/test_command.out => build/test/out/test_command_runner.o
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Do someone has ready-to-go configuration for Ceedling for STM32 microcontroller?

Comment: Your build problem here is that you have defined UNITY_INCLUDE_CONFIG_H but haven't provided a unity_config.h file. Really though, I recommend testing on your host first -- make your code endian agnostic. See https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994674/how-to-write-endian-agnostic-c-c-code

Comment: I will check unity_config.h. It was 3 months ago - I've tested it on host with endian agnostic tests. That was the only solution normal solution for this sitauation.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for my STM32G0 setup

```
# Ceedling configuration to run unit testing with code coverage using GCC compiler and the 
# STM32CubeG0 library, user only has to type make test target from the makefile to run
# all the unit test cases written on files in folder test 
:project:
  :build_root: Build/ceedling/       # Directory where ceedling will place its output
  :use_test_preprocessor: TRUE
  :use_auxiliary_dependencies: TRUE
  :test_file_prefix: test_


# Project paths for test and source and header files
:paths:
  :test:
    - test/**           # directory where the unit testing are
  :source:
    - app/**            # directory where the functions to test are
    - halg0/Src         # HAL library source files
    - cmsisg0/startups  # HAL library system source file
  :include:
    - halg0/Inc         # HAL library include files
    - cmsisg0/core      # HAL library CPU definitions in header files
    - cmsisg0/registers # HAL library register definition files


# Global defines applicable only when you run the code using ceedling
:defines:
  :test:
    - UTEST           # define the macro UTEST to remove the static qualifier
    - STM32G0B1xx     # HAL library microcontroller in use
    - USE_HAL_DRIVER  # HAL library to active HAL driver func tions


# Plugins to add extra fcuntionality to ceedling, like code coverage and pretty reports
:plugins: 
  :load_paths:
    - "#{Ceedling.load_path}"
  :enabled:
    - stdout_pretty_tests_report  # Display test cases result in a better way
    - gcov                        # Code coverage


# enable and configure code coverage
:gcov:
  :abort_on_uncovered: true   # Stop if a file under test has not been tested
  :utilities:
    - gcovr                   # gcovr for report generation
  :reports:
    - HtmlDetailed            # genarate a detail report of each file in  HTML
  :uncovered_ignore_list:
    - halg0/**                # Ignore files in HAL library
    - cmsisg0/**              # Ignore files in HAL library
    - app/main.c              # Ignore main file (renmove from here ig needed)
    - app/ints.c              # Do not test interrupt vectors
    - app/msps.c              # Do not test extra initlization functions


# Configure the mock generator
:cmock:
  :mock_prefix: mock_         # Generate mock version using mock prefix
  :treat_externs: :include
  :when_no_prototypes: :warn
  :enforce_strict_ordering: TRUE
  :includes:
    - stm32g0xx.h             # Include by default this header on each mock file
  :strippables:              # Add here all fucntions you do not want to be mocked
    - '(?:HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Rising_Callback\s*\(+.*?\)+)'     # For instance the callback functions
    - '(?:HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Falling_Callback\s*\(+.*?\)+)'    # For instance the callback functions
  :plugins:
    - :ignore                 # Generate <function>_Ignore and <function>_IgnoreAndReturn
    - :ignore_arg             # Generate <function>_IgnoreArg_<param_name>
    - :expect_any_args        # Generate <function>_func_ExpectAnyArgs and <function>_func_ExpectAnyArgsAndReturn
    - :array                  # Generate <function>_ExpectWithArray and <function>_ExpectWithArrayAndReturn
    - :callback               # Generate <function>_ 
    - :return_thru_ptr        # Generate <function>_ReturnArrayThruPtr_<param_name> and <function>_ReturnMemThruPtr_<param_name>


# extra flags to add to default compiler GCC whe run commands ceedling test:all and ceedling gcov:all
# these flags are the same written in the makefile used to build the project plus three extra flags
# for some reason are needed by GCC to avoid cast warnings in HAL library
:flags:
  :test:        # flags when GCC runs with ceedling test:all
    :compile:
      :*:
        - -O0
        - -ffunction-sections
        - -fdata-sections
        - -fno-builtin
        - -std=c11
        - -pedantic
        - -Wall
        - -Werror
        - -Wstrict-prototypes
        - -fsigned-char
        - -fomit-frame-pointer
        - -fverbose-asm
        # Extra flags to avoid cast warnings in the HAL library
        - -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast 
        - -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast
        - -Wno-error=address
  :gcov:        # flags when GCC runs with ceedling gcov:all
    :compile:
      :*:
        - -O0
        - -ffunction-sections
        - -fdata-sections
        - -fno-builtin
        - -std=c11
        - -pedantic
        - -Wall
        - -Werror
        - -Wstrict-prototypes
        - -fsigned-char
        - -fomit-frame-pointer
        - -fverbose-asm
        # Extra flags to avoid cast warnings in the HAL library
        - -Wno-int-to-pointer-cast 
        - -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast
        - -Wno-error=address
```