# Converting an assembly jump command to its hex value in C

Tags: c, assembly

Im attempting to create an assembler in c which just reads the instructions from an input file and then translates them to their machine/hex code. So far so good until i hit the jump instruction, while i have it so that it translates the hex properly to in the case of `jump 24` to `c0 00 00 18` im unsure of how to check those 00's properly without hard coding it in. How can i do this? Should i be using shifts?

**PR1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ltrim(char *s) {
    while (*s == ' ' || *s == '\t') s++;
    return s;
}

char getRegister(char *text) {
    if (*text == 'r' || *text=='R') text++;
    return atoi(text);
}

char getHex(char *text){
    int number = (int)strtol(text, NULL, 16);
    char reservednum[5];
    if(number <= 0xFFFF){
        sprintf(&reservednum[0], "%04x", number);
    }
    return atoi(reservednum);
}

int assembleLine(char *text, unsigned char* bytes) {
    text = ltrim(text);
    char *keyWord = strtok(text," ");
    if (strcmp("add",keyWord) == 0) {
        bytes[0] = 0x10;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL," "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL," ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL," "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("subtract", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x50;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("and", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x20;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("divide", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x30;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("multiply", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x40;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("or", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x60;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("halt", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x00;
        bytes[1] = 0x00;
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("return", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x70;
        bytes[1] = 0x00;
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("addimmediate", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x90;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("interrupt", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x80;
        bytes[0] |= getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = 0x00;
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("push", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x70;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = 0x40;
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("pop", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0x70;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = 0x80;
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("load", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0xE0;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("store", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0xF0;
        bytes[0] |= getRegister(strtok(NULL, " "));
        bytes[1] = getRegister(strtok(NULL, " ")) << 4 | getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp("jump", keyWord) == 0){
        bytes[0] = 0xC0;
        bytes[1] = 0x00;
        bytes[2] = 0x00;
        bytes[3] = getHex(strtok(NULL, " "));
        return 4;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *src = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    FILE *dst = fopen(argv[2],"w");
    while (!feof(src)) {
        unsigned char bytes[4];
        char line[1000];
        if (NULL != fgets(line, 1000, src)) {
            printf ("read: %s\n",line);
            int byteCount = assembleLine(line,bytes);
            fwrite(bytes,byteCount,1,dst);
        }
    }
    fclose(src);
    fclose(dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps because you told `strtol` to parse the input number as base 16?  Your expected output would make sense if you'd parsed it as decimal and then looked at a hexdump of the binary output.  Otherwise you'd expect `24` on input to be 0x24 on output, because it should parse as 2*16 + 4*1.  Use a debugger to check values inside your program.

Comment: Also, if your ISA is variable-length, why are you bothering with 2 bytes of zeros in your `jump` encoding?  Why not memcpy 3 bytes or something (to use host endian) or use shifts to extract the low 3 bytes of the jump offset?  Or make `jump` a 1-byte displacement.

Comment: Without being a pain perhaps could i ask for an example of using shifts to extract the lower 3 bytes of the jump offset? Thats something that i think could also be useful for branches as well. If im correct, Jump is actually a 32 bit instruction, opcode first 4, then next 12 are  top 12 of jump address and next 16 are lower 16 of the address. I inserted the double 0's in there mostly as placeholders but i know thats not right, im just unsure of how to be able to extract that jump address while maintaining the 32 bit structure for output of `C0 00 00 18` for this case

Comment: the variable length  comes from the differing of the length of instruction, some are 16 bit some are 32

Comment: Yeah I can see that some are 16.  Unless your current implementation is just a placeholder (which apparently is the case, but there's not even a TODO comment on it), my point was that you should make `jump` a 16-bit instruction instead of wasting 2 bytes on zeros.  re: shifts: [How to write endian agnostic C/C++ code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13994674)

Comment: The jump instruction itself is a 32-bit instruction though by the nature of assembly, me reconstructing that to be a 16-bit isnt an option. Thats why i was wondering how i could do this in a way that checked the top 12 bits, clearly in this case setting them to 0's and then checked the bottom 16 bits which should in this case be `00 18`. I am just unsure how to produce this

Comment: This is a toy ISA you're inventing, isn't it?  Anyway, not that it matters, clearly you *want* a large immediate for your jump instruction so long-range jumps are encodeable.  Some variable-length ISAs (e.g. x86) have both a short (imm8) and large (imm32) jump.

Comment: Figured out my hex issues with some reworking but im a bit confused still on how to check the top 16 bits to ensure they are 0's or if perhaps they arent. How can i do this?

Comment: Right shift by 16 and look at what's left.

Comment: would i do this by per say `bytes[1] = getHex(strtok(NULL, " ")) >> 16` ? When i attempted this it gave me a segmentation fault dump

Comment: No, you'd read one `uint32_t` into a tmp variable and extract the bytes of that.  Obviously you can't keep calling `strtok` multiple times.  (Then use a debugger to look at your tmp vars.)

Comment: ahhh okay so i strtok once, get the 24. convert that to hex, then i store it into a temp var, extract the bytes that way and use the variables with the extracted bytes as the inputs for bytes 1-3? Is there anychance you can show me a mock example to go off of for this?

Comment: What i had just been trying is to store it all into byte 0 and do a shift right 28 but that didnt work as planned with `bytes[0] = 0xC0` `bytes0 |= getHex(strtok(NULL, " ")) >> 28`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994674/how-to-write-endian-agnostic-c-c-code/13995796#13995796) is what I told you to look at earlier.