# Convert uint64_t to byte array portably and optimally in Clang

Tags: c++, clang, endianness

If you want to convert `uint64_t` to a `uint8_t[8]` (little endian). On a little endian architecture you can just do an ugly `reinterpret_cast<>` or `memcpy()`, e.g:

```cpp
void from_memcpy(const std::uint64_t &x, uint8_t* bytes) {
    std::memcpy(bytes, &x, sizeof(x));
}
```

This generates efficient assembly:

```
mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
mov     qword ptr [rsi], rax
ret
```

However it is not portable. It will have different behaviour on a little endian machine.

For converting `uint8_t[8]` to `uint64_t` there is a great solution - just do this:

```cpp
void to(const std::uint8_t* bytes, std::uint64_t &x) {
    x = (std::uint64_t(bytes[0]) << 8*0) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[1]) << 8*1) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[2]) << 8*2) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[3]) << 8*3) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[4]) << 8*4) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[5]) << 8*5) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[6]) << 8*6) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[7]) << 8*7);
}
```

This looks inefficient but actually with Clang `-O2` it generates exactly the same assembly as before, and if you compile on a big endian machine it will be smart enough to use a native byte swap instruction. E.g. this code:

```cpp
void to(const std::uint8_t* bytes, std::uint64_t &x) {
    x = (std::uint64_t(bytes[7]) << 8*0) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[6]) << 8*1) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[5]) << 8*2) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[4]) << 8*3) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[3]) << 8*4) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[2]) << 8*5) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[1]) << 8*6) |
        (std::uint64_t(bytes[0]) << 8*7);
}
```

Compiles to:

```
mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
bswap   rax
mov     qword ptr [rsi], rax
ret
```

My question is: is there an equivalent reliably-optimised construct for converting in the opposite direction? I've tried this, but it gets compiled naively:

```cpp
void from(const std::uint64_t &x, uint8_t* bytes) {
    bytes[0] = x >> 8*0;
    bytes[1] = x >> 8*1;
    bytes[2] = x >> 8*2;
    bytes[3] = x >> 8*3;
    bytes[4] = x >> 8*4;
    bytes[5] = x >> 8*5;
    bytes[6] = x >> 8*6;
    bytes[7] = x >> 8*7;
}
```

*Edit:* After some experimentation, this code does get compiled optimally with GCC 8.1 and later as long as you use `uint8_t* __restrict__ bytes`. However I still haven't managed to find a form that Clang will optimise.

Comment: My guess is that your inverse conversion doesn’t work because you’re not masking the values and instead rely on truncation via lossy implicit conversion. Try explicitly masking the byte out. You can also put the code into a loop, IIRC clang has no issue unrolling that and recognising the pattern. *In principle* this definitely works (though GCC’s optimiser seems to be dogged by QOI issues).

Comment: I tried masking - it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Also I experimented and GCC's successful optimisation does *not* work if you put it in a loop.

Comment: Maybe this can help: [How to make GCC generate bswap instruction for big endian store without builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36497605/260411)

Comment: Unfortunately not - the answers there either use `memcpy()` or convert in the opposite direction.

Comment: I tried changing OP's code in the link I provided to just inverting the `bytes[0]` to `bytes[7]`, etc. and it seems to have worked on Godbolt. It seems the pointer assignments before and after the shifts that are the trick for the optimization.

Comment: Can you post your code as an answer if it really works? I suspect you have solved a different problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about returning a value?
Easy to reason about and small assembly:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

auto to_bytes(std::uint64_t x)
{
    std::array<std::uint8_t, 8> b;
    b[0] = x >> 8*0;
    b[1] = x >> 8*1;
    b[2] = x >> 8*2;
    b[3] = x >> 8*3;
    b[4] = x >> 8*4;
    b[5] = x >> 8*5;
    b[6] = x >> 8*6;
    b[7] = x >> 8*7;
    return b;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/FCroX5

and big endian:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct mybytearray
{
    uint8_t bytes[8];
};

auto to_bytes(uint64_t x)
{
    mybytearray b;
    b.bytes[0] = x >> 8*0;
    b.bytes[1] = x >> 8*1;
    b.bytes[2] = x >> 8*2;
    b.bytes[3] = x >> 8*3;
    b.bytes[4] = x >> 8*4;
    b.bytes[5] = x >> 8*5;
    b.bytes[6] = x >> 8*6;
    b.bytes[7] = x >> 8*7;
    return b;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/WARCqN

(std::array not available for -target aarch64_be? )

Comment: please see my comment on Flavio's answer. This still doesn't solve the issue on other big-endian architectures like MIPS, PPC or Sparc https://godbolt.org/z/t9Ck8-

Comment: @phuclv yeah i see. hm. i played around with different ideas, but couldnt come up with better code gen for your mentioned architectures. still this solution seems nice and easy, in my opinion

Comment: yeah. It seems modern compilers almost ignore the big endian architectures

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I could test based on the discussion in OP's comments:

```cpp
void from_optimized(const std::uint64_t &x, std::uint8_t* bytes) {
    std::uint64_t big;
    std::uint8_t* temp = (std::uint8_t*)&big;
    temp[0] = x >> 8*0;
    temp[1] = x >> 8*1;
    temp[2] = x >> 8*2;
    temp[3] = x >> 8*3;
    temp[4] = x >> 8*4;
    temp[5] = x >> 8*5;
    temp[6] = x >> 8*6;
    temp[7] = x >> 8*7;
    std::uint64_t* dest = (std::uint64_t*)bytes;
    *dest = big;
}
```

Looks like this will make things clearer for the compiler and let it assume the necessary parameters to optimize it (both on GCC and Clang with `-O2`).

Compiling to `x86-64` (little endian) on Clang 8.0.0 ([test on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/AyZixm)):

```
mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
mov     qword ptr [rsi], rax
ret
```

Compiling to `aarch64_be` (big endian) on Clang 8.0.0 ([test on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/XBJcg3)):

```
ldr     x8, [x0]
rev     x8, x8
str     x8, [x1]
ret
```

Comment: Looks correct to me but yeah I agree that is pretty complicated.

Comment: It's very easy to check because there are a lot of compilers for big-endian and bi-endian on godbolt like ARM, MIPS, PPC, Sparc... For ARM GCC you can use `-mbig-endian`. With Clang you can also specify the [`-target` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39114754/995714) to get any architecture you want. And [the result is not as good](https://godbolt.org/z/i0kL8l)

Comment: Doesn't it violate strict aliasing rules?

Comment: I beg to pardon. If you've read my link then you'll notice that the outputs in MIPS, PowerPC, Sparc... **aren't optimized**. Only ARM64 has good output. And you shouldn't even put a main in the godbolt link to remove the unnecessary distraction

Comment: Careful - this violates strict aliasing unless `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`. Though it probably is.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the reason why your original `from` implementation cannot be optimized is because you are passing the arguments by reference and pointer. So, the compiler has to consider the possibility that both of of them point to the very same address (or at least that they overlap). As you have 8 consecutive read and write operations to the (potentially) same address, the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) cannot be applied here.

Note, that just by removing the the `&` from the function signature, apparently [GCC already considers this as proof](https://godbolt.org/z/n6NGTH) that `bytes` does not point into `x` and thus this can safely be optimized. However, [for Clang this is not good enough](https://godbolt.org/z/CZUp8F).
Technically, of course `bytes` can point to `from`'s stack memory (aka. to `x`), but I think that would be undefined behavior and thus Clang just misses this optimization.

Your implementation of `to` doesn't suffer from this issue because you have implemented it in such a way that *first* you read all the values of `bytes` and *then* you make one big assignment to `x`. So even if `x` and `bytes` point to the same address, as you do all the reading first and all the writing afterwards (instead of mixing reads and writes as you do in `from`), this can be optimized.

[Flávio Toribio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56027525/9883438) works because it does precisely this: It reads all the values first and only then writes to the destination.

However, there are less complicated ways to achieve this:

```
void from(uint64_t x, uint8_t* dest) {
    uint8_t bytes[8];
    bytes[7] = uint8_t(x >> 8*7);
    bytes[6] = uint8_t(x >> 8*6);
    bytes[5] = uint8_t(x >> 8*5);
    bytes[4] = uint8_t(x >> 8*4);
    bytes[3] = uint8_t(x >> 8*3);
    bytes[2] = uint8_t(x >> 8*2);
    bytes[1] = uint8_t(x >> 8*1);
    bytes[0] = uint8_t(x >> 8*0);

    *(uint64_t*)dest = *(uint64_t*)bytes;
}
```

gets compiled to

```
mov     qword ptr [rsi], rdi
ret
```

on little endian and to

```
rev     x8, x0
str     x8, [x1]
ret
```

on big endian.

Note, that even if you passed `x` by reference, Clang would be able to optimize this. However, that would result in one more instruction each:

```
mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
mov     qword ptr [rsi], rax
ret
```

and

```
ldr     x8, [x0]
rev     x8, x8
str     x8, [x1]
ret
```

respectively.

Also note, that you can improve your implementation of `to` with a similar trick: Instead of passing the result by non-const reference, take the "more natural" approach and just return it from the function:

```
uint64_t to(const uint8_t* bytes) {
    return
        (uint64_t(bytes[7]) << 8*7) |
        (uint64_t(bytes[6]) << 8*6) |
        (uint64_t(bytes[5]) << 8*5) |
        (uint64_t(bytes[4]) << 8*4) |
        (uint64_t(bytes[3]) << 8*3) |
        (uint64_t(bytes[2]) << 8*2) |
        (uint64_t(bytes[1]) << 8*1) |
        (uint64_t(bytes[0]) << 8*0);
}
```

### Summary:

1. Don't pass arguments by reference.
2. Do all the reading first, then all the writing.

Here are the best solutions I could get to for both, [little endian](https://godbolt.org/z/D8iyNs) and [big endian](https://godbolt.org/z/wjwC2X). Note, how `to` and `from` are truly inverse operations that can be optimized to a no-op if executed one after another.

Comment: please stop just looking at ARM64 output and conclude that it works for other major bi/big-endian architectures like MIPS, PPC or Sparc. Yours is inefficient on those just like other answers https://godbolt.org/z/txvvZl

Answer (score 0):

The code you've given is way overcomplicated. You can replace it with:

```
void from(uint64_t x, uint8_t* dest) {
    x = htole64(x);
    std::memcpy(dest, &x, sizeof(x));
}
```

Yes, this uses the Linux-ism `htole64()`, but if you're on another platform you can easily reimplement that.

Clang and GCC optimize this perfectly, on both little- and big-endian platforms.

Comment: For some definitions of "easily", isn't this just moving the troublesome code from the question into a macro?

Comment: "you can easily reimplement that" - erm... sure. I might even ask a question about reimplementing it on StackOverflow.

Comment: @M.M: Not really, most platforms have a 64-bit version of `htonl()` already, and applications that contain code like the OP has probably would already have reimplemented that if needed.  And it's more general-purpose/modular than the OP code.