# Create Minimum perfect hash for sparse 64-bit unsigned integer

Tags: python, c, perfect-hash

I need a 64 bit to 16 bit perfect hash function for a sparsely populated list of keys.

I have a dictionary in python which has 48326 keys of length 64-bits. I would like to create a minimum perfect hash for this list of keys. (I don't want to have to wait for a few days to calculate the MPH so i am ok with it mapping to a 16 bit hash also)

The objective is to eventually port this dictionary to C as an array which contains the dict values and the index is calculated by the Minimum perfect hash function taking key as input . I cannot use external hashing libraries in the C port of the application I am building

Question:
Is there any python library which will take my keys as input and provide me the hashing parameters and (based on a defined algorithm used for hashing) as an output.

I found a library [perfection 2.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/perfection/) but since my keys are of 64 bit form, this just hung. (even when I tested it on a subset of 2000 keys)

**EDIT**
As suggested in comments I looked at [Steve Hanov's Algo](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=119) and modified the hash function to take a 64 bit integer (changing values of the FNV Prime and offset as per this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function))

while I got the result, unfortunately the Maps return -ve index values while i can make it work it means i have to add another 4 cycles to the hash calculations by checking for -ve index

would like to avoid this

Comment: Did you look at http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=119, which explains how to create a minimal perfect hash using an intermediary table and the Python code for that approach? Their timing results are very encouraging, 50k keys takes only 11 seconds.

Comment: I have looked at it. I even modified to code to take integers instead of string. given that these keys are rather large. ran for about 3 hours and hung

Comment: Have you considered converting your 64-bit key to a binary string? It'll only be 8 bytes long.

Comment: i cant do this as then i will have to convert my 64 bit int into an 8 byte which will add 24 cpu cycles to the hashing also, the current hashing also takes 24 CPU cycles already, this will significantly slow down performance

Comment: You don't need to convert anything at all; just take a pointer to your 64-bit integer and take the 8 bytes that are there. Adjust the `'little'` to `'big'` in my answer if your platform stores such an integer in big-endian order.

Comment: And hashing is 8 XOR operations and 8 multiplications, plus a modulus. There is no need to mask in C, as integer operations are already masked. So the whole thing is 17 CPU operations, nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd just generate a table with [`gperf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/), or for a large number of keys, with [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/), and be done with it.

If you must do this in Python, then I found [this blog post](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=119) with some Python 2 code that is very efficient at turning *string* keys into a minimal perfect hash, using an intermediary table.

Adapting the code in the post to your requirements, produces a minimal perfect hash for 50k items in under 0.35 seconds:

```
>>> import random
>>> testdata = {random.randrange(2**64): random.randrange(2**64)
...             for __ in range(50000)}  # 50k random 64-bit keys
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('gen_minimal_perfect_hash(testdata)', 'from __main__ import  gen_minimal_perfect_hash, testdata', number=10)
3.461486832005903
```

The changes I made:

- I switched to Python 3, followed the Python styleguide and make the code more Pythonic
- I am turning 64-bit unsigned integers into 8-byte bytestrings with [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)
- Instead of storing negative numbers, I am using a flag to distinguish between direct and hash-input values in the intermediary table

The adapted code:

```
# Easy Perfect Minimal Hashing
# By Steve Hanov. Released to the public domain.
# Adapted to Python 3 best practices and 64-bit integer keys by Martijn Pieters
#
# Based on:
# Edward A. Fox, Lenwood S. Heath, Qi Fan Chen and Amjad M. Daoud,
# "Practical minimal perfect hash functions for large databases", CACM, 35(1):105-121
# also a good reference:
# Compress, Hash, and Displace algorithm by Djamal Belazzougui,
# Fabiano C. Botelho, and Martin Dietzfelbinger
from itertools import count, groupby


def fnv_hash_int(value, size, d=0x811c9dc5):
    """Calculates a distinct hash function for a given 64-bit integer.

    Each value of the integer d results in a different hash value. The return
    value is the modulus of the hash and size.

    """
    # Use the FNV algorithm from http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/
    # The unsigned integer is first converted to a 8-character byte string.
    for c in value.to_bytes(8, 'big'):
        d = ((d * 0x01000193) ^ c) & 0xffffffff

    return d % size


def gen_minimal_perfect_hash(dictionary, _hash_func=fnv_hash_int):
    """Computes a minimal perfect hash table using the given Python dictionary.

    It returns a tuple (intermediate, values). intermediate and values are both
    lists. intermediate contains the intermediate table of indices needed to
    compute the index of the value in values; a tuple of (flag, d) is stored, where
    d is either a direct index, or the input for another call to the hash function.
    values contains the values of the dictionary.

    """
    size = len(dictionary)

    # Step 1: Place all of the keys into buckets
    buckets = [[] for __ in dictionary]
    intermediate = [(False, 0)] * size
    values = [None] * size

    for key in dictionary:
        buckets[_hash_func(key, size)].append(key)

    # Step 2: Sort the buckets and process the ones with the most items first.
    buckets.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    # Only look at buckets of length greater than 1 first; partitioned produces
    # groups of buckets of lengths > 1, then those of length 1, then the empty
    # buckets (we ignore the last group).
    partitioned = (g for k, g in groupby(buckets, key=lambda b: len(b) != 1))
    for bucket in next(partitioned, ()):
        # Try increasing values of d until we find a hash function
        # that places all items in this bucket into free slots
        for d in count(1):
            slots = {}
            for key in bucket:
                slot = _hash_func(key, size, d=d)
                if values[slot] is not None or slot in slots:
                    break
                slots[slot] = dictionary[key]
            else:
                # all slots filled, update the values table; False indicates
                # these values are inputs into the hash function
                intermediate[_hash_func(bucket[0], size)] = (False, d)
                for slot, value in slots.items():
                    values[slot] = value
                break

    # The next group is buckets with only 1 item. Process them more quickly by
    # directly placing them into a free slot.
    freelist = (i for i, value in enumerate(values) if value is None)

    for bucket, slot in zip(next(partitioned, ()), freelist):
        # These are 'direct' slot references
        intermediate[_hash_func(bucket[0], size)] = (True, slot)
        values[slot] = dictionary[bucket[0]]

    return (intermediate, values)


def perfect_hash_lookup(key, intermediate, values, _hash_func=fnv_hash_int):
    "Look up a value in the hash table defined by intermediate and values"
    direct, d = intermediate[_hash_func(key, len(intermediate))]
    return values[d if direct else _hash_func(key, len(values), d=d)]
```

The above produces two lists with 50k entries each; the values in the first table are `(boolean, integer)` tuples with the integers in the range `[0, tablesize)` (in theory the values could range up to 2^16 but I'd be very surprised if it ever took 65k+ attempts to find a slot arrangement for your data). Your table size is < 50k, so the above arrangement makes it possible to store the entries in this list in 4 bytes (`bool` and `short` make 3, but [alignment rules](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) add one byte padding) when expressing this as a C array.

A quick test to see of the hash tables are correct and produce the right output again:

```
>>> tables = gen_minimal_perfect_hash(testdata)
>>> for key, value in testdata.items():
...     assert perfect_hash_lookup(key, *tables) == value
...
```

You only need to implement the lookup function in C:

- The `fnv_hash_int` operation can take a pointer to your 64-bit integer, then just cast that pointer to an array of 8-bit values and increment an index 8 times to access each separate byte; use a [suitable function to ensure big-endian (network) order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022552/is-there-any-standard-htonl-like-function-for-64-bits-integers-in-c).
- You don't need to mask with `0xffffffff` in C, as overflow on a C integer value is automatically discarded anyway.
- `len(intermediate) == len(values) == len(dictionary)` and can be captured in a constant.
- Assuming C99, store the intermediate table as an array of a struct type with `flag` being a `bool`, `d` as an unsigned `short`; that's just 3 bytes, plus 1 padding byte to align on a 4-byte boundary. The datatype in the `values` array depends on the values in your input dictionary.

If you forgive my C skills, here's a sample implementation:

`mph_table.h`

```c
#include "mph_generated_table.h"
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#ifndef htonll
// see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3022552
#define htonll(x) ((1==htonl(1)) ? (x) : ((uint64_t)htonl((x) & 0xFFFFFFFF) << 32) | htonl((x) >> 32))
#endif

uint64_t mph_lookup(uint64_t key);
```

`mph_table.c`

```c
#include "mph_table.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define FNV_OFFSET 0x811c9dc5
#define FNV_PRIME 0x01000193

uint32_t fnv_hash_modulo_table(uint32_t d, uint64_t key) {
    d = (d == 0) ? FNV_OFFSET : d;
    uint8_t* keybytes = (uint8_t*)&key;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        d = (d * FNV_PRIME) ^ keybytes[i];
    }
    return d % TABLE_SIZE;
}

uint64_t mph_lookup(uint64_t key) {
    _intermediate_entry entry = 
        mph_tables.intermediate[fnv_hash_modulo_table(0, htonll(key))];
    return mph_tables.values[
        entry.flag ?
            entry.d : 
            fnv_hash_modulo_table((uint32_t)entry.d, htonll(key))];
}
```

which would rely on a generated header file, produced from:

```
from textwrap import indent

template = """\
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define TABLE_SIZE %(size)s

typedef struct _intermediate_entry {
    bool flag;
    uint16_t d;
} _intermediate_entry;
typedef struct mph_tables_t {
    _intermediate_entry intermediate[TABLE_SIZE];
    uint64_t values[TABLE_SIZE];
} mph_tables_t;

static const mph_tables_t mph_tables = {
    {  // intermediate
%(intermediate)s
    },
    {  // values
%(values)s
    }
};
"""

tables = gen_minimal_perfect_hash(dictionary)
size = len(dictionary)
cbool = ['false, ', 'true,  ']
perline = lambda i: zip(*([i] * 10))
entries = (f'{{{cbool[e[0]]}{e[1]:#06x}}}' for e in tables[0])
intermediate = indent(',\n'.join([', '.join(group) for group in perline(entries)]), ' ' * 8)
entries = (format(v, '#018x') for v in tables[1])
values = indent(',\n'.join([', '.join(group) for group in perline(entries)]), ' ' * 8)

with open('mph_generated_table.h', 'w') as generated:
    generated.write(template % locals())
```

where `dictionary` is your input table.

Compiled with `gcc -O3` the hash function is inlined (loop unrolled) and the whole `mph_lookup` function clocks in at 300 CPU instructions. A quick benchmark looping through all 50k random keys I generated shows my 2.9 GHz Intel Core i7 laptop can look up 50 million values for those keys per second (0.02 microseconds per key).

Comment: Marking as answer, because it suits my needs in terms of performance. Thought the methodology is fine... i have issue with the fact that FNV requires a double hash to retrieve value, is there any #function in which i can retrieve value in single #?

Comment: @SiddharthChabra: Take a look at the CMPH site; they document all the algorithms that the tool supports. I haven't read through those in detail, so I can't tell you if there are any that run a hash function just once to map key to value in a MPH.

Comment: @SiddharthChabra: and I'd really not get hung up on how many times the hash function is invoked. It's still O(1) constant time to look up the value so you should see this as a *single compound call*; for some values the hash function is just a little shorter, for others there are 8 more xor / multiplication steps involved.