# Problem using 64 bit data in 32 bit processor (ARM Cortex A9)

Tags: c, arm

First of all, context: I'm implementing a program in ARM Cortex A9 processor. I had an issue related to the C code itself which was solved here: [How to set the values of an array to a single variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56616473/how-to-set-the-values-of-an-array-to-a-single-variable)

First I wrote the code in my computer (OS Linux 64 bits) and the accepted answer in the above link works. However, when I did the same in the ARM A9 it didn't. I did a simple test on ARM:

```
uint64_t test = 0x1B26B354A1CF;
printf("%lx", test);
```

it prints:

> d

The same in my computer:

```
 uint64_t test = 0x1B26B354A1CF;
 printf("%lx \n", test);
```

prints:

> 1b26b354a1cf

So it seems like an overflow problem or a problem handling that "big" data. How can I find a workaround or an alternative solution to this?

Target: ARTY Z7 FPGA (in this problem you can ignore the "FPGA" part. I'm just workint with the processor this board has: ARM A9 CORTEX)

Comment: Are you using newlib? Are you targeting embedded devices or fill linux? what is `xil_printf`?

Comment: @KamilCuk Not I'm not using newlib. Added the "target device" on the post. To be honest, I don't know what is xil_printf, since I couldn't find documentation. But it was used among all the tutorials and works I saw using the same board I'm using now. I changed it to printf to avoid confusion. The only thing I found was "printf is buffered and xil_printf isn't buffered".

Comment: Check if your library printf supports 64 bits number printing. Many do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For normal [`printf` (and family)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf) the format to print a `unsigned long long` (which `uint64_t` most likely is) in hexadecimal is `"%llx"`. Note the extra `l` size prefix.

Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

What is most likely happening is that `long` is 32 bits on your 32-bit system, and 64-bits on your home system, that's why it seems to work on your home system.

Comment: You're right. I just tested it. So I shouldn't have problems using 64 bits data in 32  bits system right? Because I had undefined behavior with another part of my code but maybe it's another problem of how I'm handling the data.

Comment: @MiguelDuranDiaz No there's shouldn't be any problems of using 64-bit datatypes on a 32-bit system.

Comment: The proper way to print a `uint64_t` is not to guess that `%llx` might work but to include `<inttypes.h>` and use `”%” PRIx64`, as in `printf("%” PRIx64 “\n", test);`

Comment: @EricPostpischil Which is why I upvoted the answer by Kit. I'll keep this as it explains what happened.

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems in your code:

1. You don't know which suffix to use to define an `uint64_t` literal on your target platform.
2. You don't know which format specifier to use in `printf` for `uint64_t` values on your target platform.

Both can be solved by [using macros defined in stdint.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer).

In particular, to define a literal and assign it to a variable:

```
uint64_t test = UINT64_C(0x1B26B354A1CF);
```

To print the variable's hexadecimal value in `printf`:

```
printf("%" PRIx64 "\n", test);
```

This is guaranteed to work on any platform that properly supports `uint64_t`, no matter how many bits its processor is.

While the language itself does not require you to use a suffix for integer literals in *most* cases - a notable exception is using a literal directly as an argument for a variadic function like `printf` - doing it explicitly is a good practice in general and may be mandatory in code guidelines of safety-critical projects. For example, the Rule 10.6 of MISRA C:2004 guidelines requires the use of `U` suffix for all unsigned constants.

Comment: I read the page, but couldn't figure out how I should use them. There I saw the data types (which I'm already using with uint64_t) and the maximum values of each. Can you elaborate on how to use them?

Comment: C automatically selects a sufficiently wide type for constants. The lack of a suffix is not a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the suffix for defining the unsigned 64-bit literal, you can check what suffix is used in your `stdint.h` for `#define UINT64_MAX`. In my case, a macro called `__UINT64_C(c)` is used to paste the suffix `UL` after the literal if my word size is 64, or `ULL` if my word size is 32.

Comment: `__UINT64_C` is not portable. The standard C header defines `UINT64_C` (if the implementation supports `uint64_t`), so that is generally preferred. However, a suffix is not needed when simply assigning a constant to an integer object. C will automatically select a sufficiently wide type for the constant. An explicit type is only needed if the value is being used in a context where the type matters (for example, in a shift expression).

Comment: I figured it the macro was specific to my platform, but I didn't realize there was a standard counterpart. That is good to know. I'm not sure why `__UINT64_C` was not merely defined as `UINT64_C` in my header, given that they are defined identically.