# How to write this php code in c++

Tags: php, c++, websocket

```
$x = pack("N", $num1).pack("N", $num2).$data;
```

I am trying to do it with

```
 union unionchal {
  struct ast{
   unsigned long a;
   unsigned long b;
   char c[8];
  } chal;
  unsigned char response[16];
 };
```

ast being the input and response being the output

It is meant to output `yp¶ ‚¬þÖHpö€ì_±` but gives `¶pyßêÈ)ÖHpöì_`

I think it's got something to do with it being big endian byte order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`htonl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/htonl.html) on your integers before placing them into the structure. It will convert them into big-endian order. If you need 64-bit longs, see [the discussion about it on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809902/64-bit-ntohl-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

> I think it's got something to do with
>   it being big endian byte order

I also think so. You may use htonl() for example, to change the byte order on little-endian machines, or write your own byte-swapping function (but then you'll have to test yourself what the byte order of the host machine is).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/variant.html#variant.intro) library.