# C - Error with read() of a file, storage in an array, and printing output properly

Tags: c, file, double, printf

I am new to C, so I am not exactly sure where my error is. However, I do know that the great portion of the issue lies either in how I am storing the doubles in the d_buffer (double) array or the way I am printing it.

Specifically, my output keeps printing extremely large numbers (with around 10-12 digits before the decimal point and a trail of zeros after it. Additionally, this is an adaptation of an older program to allow for double inputs, so I only really added the two if statements (in the "read" for loop and the "printf" for loop) and the d_buffer declaration.

I would appreciate any input whatsoever as I have spent several hours on this error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


struct DataDescription
{
   char fieldname[30];
   char fieldtype;
   int  fieldsize;
};




/* -----------------------------------------------
   eof(fd): returns 1 if file `fd' is out of data
   ----------------------------------------------- */
int eof(int fd)
{
   char c;

   if ( read(fd, &c, 1) != 1 )
      return(1);
   else
    { lseek(fd, -1, SEEK_CUR);
      return(0);
    }
}


void main()
{
   FILE *fp;    /* Used to access meta data */
   int fd;  /* Used to access user data */

   /* ----------------------------------------------------------------
      Variables to hold the description of the data  - max 10 fields
      ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
   struct DataDescription DataDes[10];  /* Holds data descriptions
                                           for upto 10 fields */
   int  n_fields;                       /* Actual # fields */

   /* ------------------------------------------------------
      Variables to hold the data  - max 10 fields....
      ------------------------------------------------------ */
   char c_buffer[10][100];  /* For character data */
   int  i_buffer[10];       /* For integer data */
   double d_buffer[10];

   int i, j;
   int found;

   printf("Program for searching a mini database:\n");

   /* =============================
      Read in meta information
      ============================= */
   fp = fopen("db-description", "r");
   n_fields = 0;
   while ( fscanf(fp, "%s %c %d", DataDes[n_fields].fieldname, 
          &DataDes[n_fields].fieldtype,
          &DataDes[n_fields].fieldsize) > 0 )
      n_fields++;

   /* ---
      Prints meta information
      --- */
   printf("\nThe database consists of these fields:\n");
   for (i = 0; i < n_fields; i++)
      printf("Index %d: Fieldname `%s',\ttype = %c,\tsize = %d\n", 
        i, DataDes[i].fieldname, DataDes[i].fieldtype,
        DataDes[i].fieldsize);
   printf("\n\n");

   /* ---
      Open database file
      --- */
   fd = open("db-data", O_RDONLY);

   /* ---
      Print content of the database file
      --- */
   printf("\nThe database content is:\n");
   while ( ! eof(fd) )
   {  /* ------------------
         Read next record
         ------------------ */
      for (j = 0; j < n_fields; j++)
      {  
     if ( DataDes[j].fieldtype == 'I' )
        read(fd, &i_buffer[j], DataDes[j].fieldsize);
     if ( DataDes[j].fieldtype == 'F' )
        read(fd, &d_buffer[j], DataDes[j].fieldsize);
     if ( DataDes[j].fieldtype == 'C' )
        read(fd, &c_buffer[j], DataDes[j].fieldsize);       
      }

      double d;
      /* ------------------
         Print it...
         ------------------ */
      for (j = 0; j < n_fields; j++)
      {   
     if ( DataDes[j].fieldtype == 'I' )
        printf("%d ", i_buffer[j]);
     if ( DataDes[j].fieldtype == 'F' )
        d = d_buffer[j];
        printf("%lf ", d);
     if ( DataDes[j].fieldtype == 'C' )
        printf("%s ", c_buffer[j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
   }
   printf("\n");
   printf("\n");


}
```

Expected Output:
3 rows of data ending with the number "e = 2.18281828"

To reproduce the problem, the following two files need to be in the same directory as the lookup-data.c file:

- [db-data][1]

- [db-description][2]

Comment: How does one populate the database and index to reproduce the problem?

Comment: We can't reproduce your problem because we don't have the input files.  If you can't share those files, could you please share the output you are getting?  I'm interested to know what `fieldsize` is for the float values.

Comment: Please learn about the switch statement, and use it. And you aren't checking the return value of read ... doing that would be a lot better than your funky eof function.

Comment: Your new `printf()` for the float value is using format code `"%d"`; it should be `"%f"`.

Comment: It is a little bit confusing: you have three database records, and each record has three fields.  In your loop that reads the records, you should always read the three fields.  Get rid of the `if` statements and just do three calls to `read()` each time.  Likewise, when printing, you always should print three field values; you can do a single `printf()` with three format codes if you like, or three calls to `printf()` as you have now, if you prefer.

Comment: I'm going to try to remember this forever: a big-endian `1` read on a little-endian machine prints as `16777216`.  That's 2 raised to the 24th power.  It works the other way, too: a little-endian `1` read on a big-endian machine will also print as `16777216`.  If I had memorized that, I could have figured this out much faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: My earlier speculations were all wrong.  The problem was that the database file had big-endian numbers and the data were being read on a little-endian computer.  Skip down to the section marked "START READING HERE" to avoid wasting your time with the early speculations (left here for their very limited historical value).

I suspect that your problem is related to the `printf()` format specification `%lf` used to print values, together with the fact that you declared `d_buffer` to be of type `int`.  Likely `sizeof(double) > sizeof(int)` is true, so you are interpreting extra bytes of data to be part of the float values.

I don't know this for sure since I can't see the data your program is using to run, but if your `fieldsize` for float data is `sizeof(float)` rather than `sizeof(double)` then perhaps you are storing the float values into `d_buffer` just fine but messing them up when printing.  Alternatively, if `fieldsize` is equal to `sizeof(double)`, and `sizeof(double)` is greater than `sizeof(int)`, then you are writing off the end of `d_buffer` and then something is corrupting your data.

I suggest you change the declaration to `double d_buffer[10];` and see if your program works better.  Also, see if `fieldsize` is set to `sizeof(float)` or `sizeof(double)`; if it is `sizeof(float)` then declare `d_buffer` as type `float` and use this code:

```
  if ( DataDes[j].fieldtype == 'F' )
  {
    double d = d_buffer[j];
    printf("%lf ", d);
  }
```

EDIT: Also, I recommend that you switch to using `fopen()` and `fread()` for all your I/O.  The basic `open()` and `read()` can return `EINTR` which means you need to retry the operation, so these are only properly used inside a loop that will retry the call if it returns `EINTR`.  The `fopen()` and `fread()` calls insulate you from that sort of detail, and have some buffering that can make your programs run more smoothly.  (I'm pretty sure your current project is only reading and writing small amounts of data, so the performance difference likely doesn't matter much to you at this time.)

Also, I suggest you get rid of your `eof()` function; it is very unusual and likely a bit slow to read a character and then use `fseek()` to put it back.  The C library has the function `fgetc()` which gets one character from the input stream, and you can test that character to see if it is the `EOF` value to detect end-of-file.  And the C library also has the function `ungetc()` that can push back one character; this will not involve actually seeking the disk, but rather will just put back the character into some buffer somewhere.  But you don't even need to use `fgetc()` or `ungetc()` for your code; just check the return value from `fread()` and if you get a zero-length read, you know you hit end-of-file.  In production code, you will need to check the return value of each function call anyway; you can't get away with just hoping that every read succeeds.

EDIT: One more thing you could try: change the format code from `"%lf"` to just `"%f"` and see what happens.  I'm not exactly sure what that `l` will do and you shouldn't need it.  Plain old `"%f"` should format a `double`.  But it may not change anything: according to this web page I found, in `printf()` there is no difference between `"%lf"` and `"%f"`.

http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/printf.html

*** START READING HERE ***

EDIT: Okay, one thing I have figured out for sure.  The database format is an index value (an integer value), then a float value, then a string value.  You will need to read each one to advance the current position within the file.  So your current code that is checking format codes and deciding which thing to read?  Not correct; you need to read an integer, a float, and a string for each record.

EDIT: Okay, here is a correct Python program that can read the database.  It doesn't bother to read the metadata file; I just hard-coded in the constants (it's okay since it is just a throw-away program).

```
import struct

_format_rec = ">id20s"  # big-endian: int, double, 20-char string
_cb_rec = struct.calcsize(_format_rec) # count of bytes in this format

def read_records(fname):
    with open(fname) as in_f:
        try:
            while True:
                idx, f, s = struct.unpack(_format_rec, in_f.read(_cb_rec))
                # Python doesn't chop at NUL byte by default so do it now.
                s, _, _ = s.partition('\0')
                yield (idx, f, s)
        except struct.error:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i, (idx, f, s) in enumerate(read_records("db-data")):
        print "%d) index: %d\tfloat: %f \ttext: \"%s\"" % (i, idx, f, s)
```

So the index values are 32-bit integers, big-endian; the floats are 64-bit floats, big-endian; and the text fields are 20 characters fixed (so a string of 0 to 19 characters plus a terminating NUL byte).

Here's the output of the above program:

```
0) index: 1     float: 3.141593         text: "Pi"
1) index: 2     float: 12.345000        text: "Secret Key"
2) index: 3     float: 2.718282         text: "The number E"
```

Now, when I try to compile your C code, I get garbage values out because my computer is little-endian.  Are you trying to run your C code on a little-endian computer?

EDIT: To answer the most recent comment, which is a question: For each input record, you must call `read()` three times.  The first time you read the index, which is a 4-byte integer (big-endian).  The second read is an 8-byte float value, also big-endian.  The third read is 20 bytes as a string.  Each read moves the current position in the file; the three reads together read a single record from the file.  After you have read and printed three records, you are done.

Since my computer is little-endian, it's tricky to get the values out correctly in C, but I did it.  I made a union that lets me read out an 8-byte value as an integer or as a float, and I used that as the buffer for the call to `read()`; then I called `__builtin_bswap64()` (a feature in GCC) to swap the big-endian value to little-endian, stored the result as a 64-bit integer, and read it out as a float.  I also used `__builtin_bswap32()` to swap the integer index.  My C program now prints:

```
The database content is:
1 3.141593 Pi
2 12.345000 Secret Key
3 2.718282 The number E
```

So, read each record, make sure you are correct with respect to endian-ness of the data, and you will have a working program.

EDIT: Here are code fragments that show how I fixed the endianness problem.

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned char buf[8];
    double d;
    int64_t i64;
    int32_t i32;
} U;

// then, inside of main():

   printf("\nThe database content is:\n");
   {  /* ------------------
         Read next record
         ------------------ */
      for (j = 0; j < n_fields; j++)
      {
        U u;
        read(fd, u.buf, 4);
        u.i32 = __builtin_bswap32(u.i32);
        i_buffer[j] = u.i32;
        read(fd, u.buf, 8);
        u.i64 = __builtin_bswap64(u.i64);
        d_buffer[j] = u.d;
        read(fd, c_buffer[j], 20);
      }
```

I'm sort of surprised the database was in big-endian format.  Any computer using an x86 family processor is little-endian.

You should definitely not hard-code those numbers (4, 8, 20) like I did; you should use the metadata you received.  I'll leave that for you.

EDIT: Also you shouldn't call `__builtin_bswap32()` or `__builtin_bswap64()`.  You should call `ntohl()` and... I'm not sure what the 64-bit one is.  But `ntohl()` is portable; it will skip the swap if you are compiling on a big-endian computer, and do the swap if you are compiling on a little-endian computer.

EDIT: I found a solution to a 64-bit equivalent to `ntohl()`, right here on StackOverflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410728/166949

It's simple if you only care about Linux: instead of using `#include <arpa/inet.h>` you can use `#include <endian.h>` and then use `be32toh()` and `be64toh()`.

Once you have this you can read the database file like so:

```
u.i64 = be64toh(u.i64);
```

If you compile the above code on a big-endian machine, it will compile to a do-nothing and read the big-endian value.  If you compile the above code on a little-endian machine, it will compile to the equivalent of `__builtin_bswap64()` and swap the bytes so the 64-bit value is read correctly.

EDIT: I said in a couple of places that you need to do three separate reads: one to get the index, one to get the float, and one to get the string.  Actually, you can declare a `struct` and issue a single read that would pull in all the data in one read.  The tricky part, though, is that the C compiler might insert "padding" bytes inside your `struct` that would cause the byte structure of the `struct` to not exactly match the byte structure of the record read from the file.  The C compiler should provide a way to control the alignment bytes (a `#pragma` statement) but I didn't want to get into the details.  For this simple program, simply reading three times solves the problem.

Comment: steveha, I made your suggested changes but I still got an unintended output. I've put it in an edit above.

Comment: Can you actually share the file db-description?

Comment: "I'm not exactly sure what that l will do" -- Well, you could read the standard and find out.

Comment: @JimBalter, I'm also suspicious of features like that `l` and whether or not the implementation got them right.  I regularly use semi-broken compilers (Microsoft and various embedded DSP processors) and I don't assume that the standard is always followed for the less common features.  Rather than reading the standard to figure them out, I tend to just not use them, unless I think I need them.  But sure, reading the documentation is always a good thing.

Comment: Concerning your last edit -- in the first for loop where I read different things in...what would I do differently? Sorry...I'm a little confused about what your suggested change is. But thanks for keeping up with it so far! 

I have limited control over the eof() function (not supposed to change it), but I might play with the fopen() and fread() methods if all else fails. Appreciate those suggestions!

Comment: Okay, if you are not supposed to change `eof()` then use it and use `read()`.  Those are not your problem anyway.  See my latest edit to my answer; I have this working now.

Comment: I'm probably running my computer little-endian (running the compiler in a Oracle VM Virtualbox Ubuntu distro terminal). Being unfamiliar with the term, that is the best answer I can offer to your question.

I am able to compile the c file, but I run it by executing a produced a.out file. Do you have a recommendation on an alternate configuration to help me achieve your output? That is, in fact, what I am supposed to get -- very helpful, since I had no way of opening the .bin file's contents prior to this. I was just told what the expected output should look like.

Comment: This is a very useful starting point. I'll work through your suggestions until I get the desired output. I'll let you know if I have any questions. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you don't know what "little-endian" means, look it up.  I suggest using Wikipedia to look it up, or just Google and find a source that will explain it.  Yes, Ubuntu running in VirtualBox is going to be little-endian.  Here, I looked it up in Wikipedia for you... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: If MS didn't follow the printf standard for %lf it would not just be "semi-broken". "Rather than reading the standard to figure them out, I tend to just not use them, unless I think I need them." That's beside the point. "But sure, reading the documentation is always a good thing." In other words, I was right.

Comment: @JimBalter, I apologize for offending you.  Have a nice life.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the results you want, I suggest replacing

```
int  d_buffer[10];
```

with:

```
double d_buffer[10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assuming that the field types you're reading from db-description match the data in db-data? I sure wouldn't. At the very least you should print out those field types and confirm that they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: I am only in charge of editing the c file, and the field types being read in from db-description do in fact match. But I didn't mention that above, so it's a good point.