# dealing with endianness in c++

Tags: c++, python, endianness

I am working on translating a system from python to c++.  I need to be able to perform actions in c++ that are generally performed by using Python's `struct.unpack` (interpreting binary strings as numerical values).  For integer values, I am able to get this to (sort of) work, using the data types in `stdint.h`:

```
struct.unpack("i", str) ==> *(int32_t*) str; //str is a char* containing the data
```

This works properly for little-endian binary strings, but fails on big-endian binary strings.  Basically, I need an equivalent to using the `>` tag in struct.unpack:

```
struct.unpack(">i", str) ==> ???
```

Please note, if there is a better way to do this, I am all ears.  However, I cannot use c++11, nor any 3rd party libraries other than Boost.  I will also need to be able to interpret floats and doubles, as in `struct.unpack(">f", str)` and `struct.unpack(">d", str)`, but I'll get to that when I solve this.

**NOTE** I should point out that the endianness of my machine is irrelevant in this case.  I know that the bitstream I receive in my code will ALWAYS be big-endian, and that's why I need a solution that will always cover the big-endian case.  The article pointed out by BoBTFish in the comments seems to offer a solution.

Comment: An interesting read: http://commandcenter.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Comment: @BoBTFish are you saying that my code is "wrong or misguided", or pointing out the solution offered in 4th paragraph?

Comment: Neither really. Well maybe the second one. Just pointing to an article that discusses this that I found interesting. I don't really feel qualified to offer a proper answer, but no one else was saying anything at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unpack the string one byte at a time.

```cpp
unsigned char *str;
unsigned int result;

result =  *str++ << 24;
result |= *str++ << 16;
result |= *str++ << 8;
result |= *str++;
```

Comment: This works for integers wit 32 bits.  Modify with moreor fewer <<'s as needed for 16 and 64 bit values.

Comment: It doesn't have a point. I suppose it would have a point if `str` were a `signed char*`. I've removed them.

Comment: @Robᵩ if str is signed, how will the `& 0xff` help?  I've realized that I am reading in the data as `char*`, but it doesnt convert properly unless I cast it to `unsigned char*`.  is there a problem just doing it that way?

Comment: @ewok `unsigned char *` is definitely the way to go for binary data.  You may unfortunately then have to sprinkle casts around for calling library functions that take plain `char *`, but it's worth it.

Answer (score 7):

**For 32 and 16-bit values:**

This is exactly the problem you have for network data, which is big-endian. You can use the the [ntohl](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl) to turn a 32-bit into host order, little-endian in your case.

> The ntohl() function converts the unsigned integer netlong from network byte order to
>          host byte order.

```
int res = ntohl(*((int32_t) str)));
```

This will also take care of the case where your host is big-endian and won't do anything.

**For 64-bit values**

Non-standardly on linux/BSD you can take a look at [64 bit ntohl() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809902/64-bit-ntohl-in-c), which points to [htobe64](http://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/3/htobe64/)

> These  functions convert the byte encoding of integer values from the byte order that
>          the current CPU (the "host") uses, to and  from  little-endian  and  big-endian  byte
>          order.

For windows try: [How do I convert between big-endian and little-endian values in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105252/how-do-i-convert-between-big-endian-and-little-endian-values-in-c)

Which points to [_byteswap_uint64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and as well as a 16 and 32-bit solution and a gcc-specific __builtin_bswap(32/64) call.

**Other Sizes**

Most systems don't have values that aren't 16/32/64 bits long. At that point I might try to store it in a 64-bit value, shift it and they translate. I'd write some good tests. I suspectt is an uncommon situation and more details would help.

Comment: 2 things:  1) note that you need to dereference the casted pointer for that to compile: `ntohl(*(int32_t*) str);`.  2) how will I handle values other than 16 and 32 bit ints?  I need to be able to cover everything from 8 to 64 bit ints, both signed and unsigned.

Comment: Thanks for the fix, it's added. Also tried to address the other size issue.

Answer (score 2):

First, the cast you're doing:

```
char *str = ...;
int32_t i = *(int32_t*)str;
```

results in undefined behavior due to the strict aliasing rule (unless `str` is initialized with something like `int32_t x; char *str = (char*)&x;`). In practical terms that cast can result in an unaligned read which causes a bus error (a crash) on some platforms and slow performance on others.

Instead you should be doing something like:

```
int32_t i;
std::memcpy(&i, c, sizeof(i));
```

---

There are a number of functions for swapping bytes between the host's native byte ordering and a host independent ordering: `ntoh*()`, `hton*()`, where `*` is nothing, `l`, or `s` for the different types supported. Since different hosts may have different byte orderings then this may be what you want to use if the data you're reading uses a consistent serialized form on all platforms.

```
ntoh(i);
```

You can also manually move bytes around in `str` before copying it into the integer.

```
std::swap(str[0],str[3]);
std::swap(str[1],str[2]);
std::memcpy(&i,str,sizeof(i));
```

Or you can manually manipulate the integer's value using shifts and bitwise operators.

```
std::memcpy(&i,str,sizeof(i));
i = (i&0xFFFF0000)>>16 | (i&0x0000FFFF)<<16;
i = (i&0xFF00FF00)>>8  | (i&0x00FF00FF)<<8;
```

Answer (score 0):

This falls in the realm of bit twiddling.

```
for (i=0;i<sizeof(struct foo);i++) dst[i] = src[i ^ mask];
```

where mask == (sizeof type -1) if the stored and native endianness differ.

With this technique one can convert a struct to bit masks:

```
 struct foo {
    byte a,b;       //  mask = 0,0
    short e;        //  mask = 1,1
    int g;          //  mask = 3,3,3,3,
    double i;       //  mask = 7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7
 } s; // notice that all units must be aligned according their native size
```

Again these masks can be encoded with two bits per symbol: `(1<<n)-1`, meaning that in 64-bit machines one can encode necessary masks of a 32 byte sized struct in a single constant (with 1,2,4 and 8 byte alignments).

```
unsigned int mask = 0xffffaa50;  // or zero if the endianness matches
for (i=0;i<16;i++) { 
     dst[i]=src[i ^ ((1<<(mask & 3))-1]; mask>>=2;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If your as received values are truly strings, (char* or std::string) and you know their format information, sscanf(), and atoi(), well, really  ato() will be your friends.  They take well formatted strings and convert them per passed-in formats (kind of reverse printf).

Comment: He says the network order is big endian, which would be irrelevant if they're being passed in text form.