# Decoding Websocket payload length in C

Tags: c, websocket, payload

```
size_t getPayloadLength(const unsigned char *inputFrame){
  size_t payloadLength = inputFrame[1] & 0x7F;

  if (payloadLength == 0x7E) {
    uint16_t payloadLength16b = 0;
    memcpy(&payloadLength16b, &inputFrame[2], 2);
    payloadLength = payloadLength16b;

  } else if (payloadLength == 0x7F) {
    uint64_t payloadLength64b = 0;
    memcpy(&payloadLength64b, &inputFrame[2], 8);
    payloadLength = (size_t)payloadLength64b;
  }

  return payloadLength;
}
```

But this method when payload is == 126 or 127 return wrong result (always enormous number) someone can spot the error?

I know i've sent a message of 250 char.
This are the first 5 byte I revive converted to binary:

```
[0] 10000001 
[1] 11111110 // & 0x7F = 126 -> so payload length is  byte 2  3 interpreted as 16 bit
[2] 00000000 //
[3] 11111010 // 0000000011111010 = 250 but my function returns 64000
[4] 10001001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the conversion of your values from network byte order to host byte order. `64000` is `11111010 00000000` in binary. You need to use the byte order conversion routines.

```
    payloadLength = ntohs(payloadLength16b);

    payloadLength = (size_t)ntohll(payloadLength64b);
```

If your system lacks a definition for `ntohll`, you can follow the suggested answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/809902/315052). But, a possible implementation might be:

```
uint64_t ntohll (uint64_t x) {
    const unsigned t = 1;
    if (*(const unsigned char *)&t) {
        x = ((uint64_t)ntohl(x & 0xffffffffU) << 32)
            | ntohl((uint32_t)(x >> 32));
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: @Gavello: `64000` is `1111101000000000` in binary, so it seems I was correct.