# be64toh not linking or being declared when compiling with -std=c99

Tags: c, compilation, linker, endianness, data-conversion

When I compile the following program (the code for all the defines I've gotten from [64 bit ntohl() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809902/64-bit-ntohl-in-c/4410728#4410728) which seemed sensible):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#if defined(__linux__)
#include <endian.h> //htobe64,be64toh
#include <arpa/inet.h> //ntohs, ntohl, htonl, htons
#elif defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__NetBSD__)
#include <sys/endian.h>
#elif defined(__OpenBSD__)
#include <sys/types.h>
#define be16toh(x) betoh16(x)
#define be32toh(x) betoh32(x)
#define be64toh(x) betoh64(x)
#endif

int main()
{
    int64_t i = 0x1212121234343434;
    int64_t j = be64toh(i);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a linking error when compiling it with the following command (I'm running linux):

```
gcc -std=c99 endian_test.c -o endian
```

The error i receive is:

```
user@host ~/src/c $ gcc -std=c99 derp.c 
endian_test.c: In function ‘main’:
endian_test.c:17:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘be64toh’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  int64_t j = be64toh(i);
  ^
/tmp/ccYonfH4.o: In function `main':
endian_test.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `be64toh'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Which to me indicates two things, the header itself is included but doesn't really contain the functions/macros needed for this to work and because that means the compiler hopes it's gonna find the function later it tries to go ahead anyway but fails when trying to link.

But if i use the following command to compile (just remove `-std=c99`):

```
gcc endian_test.c -o endian
```

Everything is smooth as butter and works. Any idea why it's happening and what i could do to remedy it? To me it doesn't make sense that functions given by the kernel (or am i mistaken in that fact?) change depending on what standard i use when compiling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could always look at the file yourself to see what it needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without explicit `-std=` option, calling `gcc` is the same as `-std=gnu89` with means C89 + GNU extensions. The GNU extensions will enable macros which will enable the presence of the functions in your header.

Comment: Does the same apply to `-std=gnu99`? And is that a feasible workaround?

Comment: Yes, it does apply to `-std=gnu99`. Both options define `__USE_BSD` macros used in `endian.h`. A workaround to your issue is to to just `#define __USE_BSD` before including `endian.h`.

Comment: That's not really portable either is it? x) I'll just keep to using gnu99 as the standard for now then. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you see the [`be64toh`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/be64toh) manual, you will see that it needs the `_BSD_SOURCE` to be defined. So on Linux `#define` it before you include `<endian.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The solution was to declare not only

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

but also

```
#define __USE_BSD
```

https://github.com/tailhook/zerogw/pull/34/files#r32008569

Answer (score 1):

Recent changes to glibc has meant you need

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
```

instead of

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

[Deprecation of _BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE feature macros](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Release/2.20#Deprecation_of__BSD_SOURCE_and__SVID_SOURCE_feature_macros)