# Saving size_t as unsigned bytes

Tags: c

I have a variable `s` of type `size_t` and a variable `buffer` of type `unsigned char`. I wish to save this variable in `buffer` in network order as 4 bytes.
How can I do it?

Comment: Are you sure `size_t` if four bytes wide on your system?

Comment: It is 64-bit system.. How can I check how wide is size_t? I can also save it as `uint32_t` or any type, which will be better for this purpose. `uint32_t` is 4 bytes on 64-bit system, isn't it?

Comment: On a 64bit system I'd expect `sizeof(size_t)` to return 8.

Comment: `uint32_t` shall be 32bits wide for any implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char c8[8] = {0};
size_t s = 0x1233456789abcdef0, s_be = 0;

if (4 == sizeof(s))
{
  s_be = htonl(s);
}
else if (8 == sizeof(s))
{
  s_be = htobe64(s);
}
else
{
  assert(0);
}

memcpy(c8, &s_be, sizeof(s_be));
```

For `htobe64()` have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410728/694576

Comment: For a pedantic solution, how about `32 == sizeof(s)*CHAR_BIT` or `sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(s)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
size_t myvar;

myvar = htonl(myvar); // For the endian issues

memcpy(buffer, &myvar, sizeof(size_t));
```