# Convert char[] to off_t

Tags: c++, c, file, char, type-conversion

I stored a filesize in a binary file and I am able to get this filesize into a `char[8]` buffer. I would like to convert this `char[]` into an `off_t` type in order to be able to pass it as an argument of `truncate(const char *path, off_t length)`.

I tried this naive approach and it seems to work most of the time, but it fails sometimes and gives me a weird sequence of bits.

```
off_t pchar_2_off_t(char* str, size_t size)
{
    off_t ret = 0;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        ret <<= 8;
        ret |= str[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Convert the `str[i]` to some sort of unsigned: `ret |= (unsigned)str[i];`

Comment: Do you know if your compilers `char` type is signed or unsigned? That may have something to do with it, as may the actual *writing* to the file.

Comment: @pmg > It doesn't seem work at all. The conversion fails.

Comment: @user1527491: `ret |= (unsigned char)str[i];`. The `str[i]` is promoted to `int` before the cast.

Comment: Alternatively, use `unsigned char` everywhere (also for the array) from the beginning. IMO, the more appropriate type anyway

Comment: How did you write it? Then reverse the serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ret |= str[i];` is a problem as `str[i]` may sign-extend upon conversion to `int`, setting many bits in `ret`.  Implied by [@pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25324/pmg) and commented by [@mafso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1741125/mafso)

```
off_t pchar_2_off_t(const char* str, size_t size) {
    off_t ret = 0;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        ret <<= 8;
        ret |= (unsigned char) str[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Note: a more pedantic solution would use `ret <<= CHAR_BIT;` as `char` width is not always 8 bits.  Seeing how OP saved `str` would clarify details.

Answer (score 1):

Just bulk-copy the data in question:

```
#include <string.h> /* for memcpy() */

...

char str[8];
/* Read 8 bytes binary data into str here. */

off_t off_file;
memcpy(&off_file, str, sizeof off_file);
```

To get around any endiness issues just do:

```
off_t off = ntohll(off_file); /* Assuming ntohll being the 64bit version of ntohl(). */
```

As `ntohll()` is non-standard please see some possible ways to implement it here: [64 bit ntohl() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/809902/694576)

Comment: Why should it be any better than a cast (user59002 answer)? It's longer to type and slower.

Comment: @user36740: I did not say it is better or worth then anything.

Comment: this has an endianness problem.

Comment: This approach assumes the same endian of `str` in the file as in `off` - which is reasonable.  OP's approach only assumes `str` endian.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: This has not more an endiness issue then casting pointers, before deferencing one and using the assignment operator.

Comment: yeah that is wrong too, and if I could comment more than once every 15 seconds I would have made that comment.

Comment: Why? @GradyPlayer The members of the ntoh/hton family of functions only convert if necessary. That is is host-byte-order and network-byte-order are different, else they are noops.

Comment: alright, your imaginary function erases my down vote

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned const char blah[8] = {0xdd,0xee,0xaa,0xdd,0xbb,0xee,0xee,0xff};
off_t * scalar = (off_t *) malloc(8);
memcpy(scalar, blah, 8);

printf("%llx\n",*scalar);
```

outputs(on my intel machine): `ffeeeebbddaaeedd`

what the wha?! you say.... there is a problem with this approach, and it is that it isn't portable ... it is a problem with [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) ...

so if you want to do this portably you need to actually either be aware of endianness and special case it or just convert with a loop:

```
*scalar = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    *scalar += (uint64_t)blah[i] << ( 8 * (7-i));
}

printf("%llx\n",*scalar);
```

outputs (on all machines that have 64bit off_t's): `ddeeaaddbbeeeeff`

Comment: This has an alignment issue.  `scalar` may be more restrictive than `blah`.

Comment: Minor: As the size of `off_t` is not necessarily the same as `unsigned long long`, using `printf("%llx\n",(unsigned long long) *scalar);` is portable.  Also `off_t` is signed.

Comment: If you do not know the endianess the data had been stored with, you have **no** 100% chance to correctly read the data.

Comment: @alk ... there is an order for elements in an array, and there is an order for most significant bytes in a scalar value... in a big endian machine these are inter changeable; on a little endian machine it isn't...

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the file that contains the filesize was created on the EXACT same machine AND that it was originally written with an `off_t` type, you can just cast the `char[]` -> an `off_t`. eg:

```
off_t filesize = *((off_t*)str);
```

Comment: You probably meant `... = *((off_t *) str);`?

Comment: If you also now would adjust your wording accordingly, this would be a valid answer ... you aren't casting to `off_t` but to `off_t *`.